# what is proper syntax for this if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I’m having a syntax error with an if statement. It was working correctly with a different version, but I’m writing to an output log and I didn’t like how it would output for every file it checked, I want it to only write once if the file exists or not.

**The first code below is the one that is not working**, it says the the third file is an undefined variable (fifth line of code).

The second code block is how it was working before.

Anyone know how to structure this?

```
if any(file.endswith('.ppt') for file in os.listdir(scanDestinationPath)):
    os.startfile(machineFolderDir + machineType + '\\' +
                 partNumber + ' REV ' + revisionNumber + '\\' +
                 file, 'print')
    errorLog = open(logBookDir + 'log.txt', 'a+')
    errorLog.write('\nA setup sheet called PROG' + programNumber +
                   ' ' + partNumber + ' ' + revisionNumber +
                   '.ppt was printed.\n')
    errorLog.close()
else:
    errorLog = open(logBookDir + 'log.txt', 'a+')
    m = ('The exception occurred in printDecoSetupSheet().There does not appear '
         f'to be a .ppt setup sheet file in folder {partNumber} {revisionNumber} '
         f'under {machineType}. Moving on...\n')
    errorLog.write(m)
    errorLog.close()
```

> Second code block:

```
    if file.endswith(".ppt"):
        os.startfile(machineFolderDir + machineType + '\\' +
                     partNumber + ' REV ' + revisionNumber + '\\' +
                     file, 'print')
        errorLog = open(logBookDir + 'log.txt', 'a+')
        errorLog.write('\nA setup sheet called PROG' + programNumber +
                       ' ' + partNumber + ' ' + revisionNumber +
                       '.ppt was printed.\n')
        errorLog.close()
    else:
        errorLog = open(logBookDir + 'log.txt', 'a+')
        m = ('The exception occurred in printDecoSetupSheet().There does not appear '
             f'to be a .ppt setup sheet file in folder {partNumber} {revisionNumber} '
             f'under {machineType}. Moving on...\n')
        errorLog.write(m)
        errorLog.close()
```

> The traceback is:
>
> ```
> Exception has occurred: NameError name 'file' is not defined   
> File "C:\Users\MacalusoC\Desktop\Technical Docs\TLC_Program_Release\Scripts\Program_Release_v4.py", line 348, in printDecoSetupSheet     
>   file, 'print')   
> File "C:\Users\MacalusoC\Desktop\Technical Docs\TLC_Program_Release\Scripts\Program_Release_v4.py", line 835, in main
>   printDecoSetupSheet(scanDestinationPath)   
> File "C:\Users\MacalusoC\Desktop\Technical Docs\TLC_Program_Release\Scripts\Program_Release_v4.py", line 869, in <module>
>   main()
> ```

Comment: Exact traceback, please.

Comment: `file` isn't defined; it's local to the generator expression passed as an argument to `any`.

Comment: Try putting [] around `file.endswith('.ppt') for file in os.listdir(scanDestinationPath)` to turn it from a generator exp to a list of bool.

Comment: This did not work, same syntax error, but thank you for the suggestion. I think my best bet is just to add a `break` after the code block in the `else` statement, since what I'm concerned with is multiple outputs to the text file, this would solve it.

Comment: @55thSwiss What you seem to want is the variable to leak out. In a generator expression, it doesn't do that. In Py2, [lists do leak variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/python-list-comprehension-rebind-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-thi), which is what KuboMD was suggesting... but even that is bad practice. Regarldess, your changed conditional also likely won't do what you expect. `any()` returns True/False, not a list, so it will only happen for one file, whatever the first ppt file it finds is... it won't log, nor process, any other files.

Comment: If you [edit] this question to include specifically what you want the result to be, that will trigger a reopen vote and you may end up getting an answer. It would also be helpful to see more of the scope: it's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish here. see [mcve] for more information.

Comment: file is a reserved keyword in python.
Can you replace `for file in` with `for _file in` and update relevant references.

Comment: Also, please include line numbers in your code-snippet aligning with the traceback.