# accessing the variable value in if loop using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Check the below code.

```py
extensionsToCheck = ['ALL QTRLY PAYMENTS', 'ATC', 'TL INTEREST', 'TL LIBOR INT']
url_string = "DCA INVESTMENT TL LIBOR INT"
if any(ext in url_string for ext in extensionsToCheck):
  print(url_string)
  print(ext)
```

I want the value of `ext` variable value, but I am not able to get this value. I am getting the following error:

> NameError: name 'ext' is not defined

How can I access the `ext` variable in if loop? Is there any way to get the `ext` variable value in if loop?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199355/494134

Comment: By `if` loop, do you mean `if` branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change a bit your logic since `any` will return you a boolean indicating if the condition you are checking is satisfied at least for one element in the list `extensionsToCheck`:

```
extensionsToCheck = ['ALL QTRLY PAYMENTS', 'ATC', 'TL INTEREST', 'TL LIBOR INT']
url_string = "DCA INVESTMENT TL LIBOR INT"
extensions = []
for ext in extensionsToCheck:
    if ext in url_string:
        # in this block you have access to
        # the variable ext that satisfy your condition
        extensions.append(ext)

print(extensions) # ['TL LIBOR INT']
```

The extensions will be in the list `extensions` if you want to print the first extension that was found use `extensions[0]`.

You can also use the following alternative:

```
extensionsToCheck = ['ALL QTRLY PAYMENTS', 'ATC', 'TL INTEREST', 'TL LIBOR INT']
url_string = "DCA INVESTMENT TL LIBOR INT"
extensions = [ext for ext in extensionsToCheck if ext in url_string]
```