# On Verification Form Always Outputs "December" For Month: webapp2 and Google App Engine (Windows 7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, webapp2

Doing the Udacity Intro to Backend course and learning basic webapp2. Relatively new to programming so I'll try to be clear. Using 64-bit Windows 7 Professional, if that matters.

One thing to note - I mostly use Python 3.6 (Anaconda) but am running 2.7 in a virtual environment. I'm not great with Python 2 and this is my first time using virtualenv.

I have a helloworld.py file which includes a class called MainPage that inherits from webapp2.RequestHandler and which contains function definitions for get and post. The file has an HTML form that asks a user to enter their birthday month, day, and year in three separate fields. There is also a submit button.

When the user enters their information, the validity of each the day, month, and year should be verified by a separate function (all three are in a separate module called verify_date). Each function basically checks that the information makes sense (no nonsense words or out-of-range dates). I am aware it doesn't enforce the differing lengths of months (eg Feb having only 28 days), but am not concerned with that.

1) If the user-entered information is valid ('January', '1', and '2000', for example) the page should accept the information and load a message that says, "Thanks for the Validation!" This works.

2) If any of the three pieces information is invalid, it should reload the form so that the user can re-enter everything. That's the issue. If I enter an out-of-range number for day or year, this works. But if I enter a made-up word into the "month" field, it A) loads the validation statement anyway, and B) writes "December" to the web page (I added a test statement) regardless of what is actually entered. For example, I could enter "April" into the box and it still prints "December." What's going on here?

NOTE: I tested the day/month/year verification functions independently in another IDE running Python 3.6, and they worked perfectly.

```
# helloworld.py

import webapp2
import verify_date

form = """
<form method="post">
    What is your birthday? 
    <br>

    <label>Month
        <input type="text" name ="month">
    </label>

    <label>Day
        <input type="text" name ="day">
    </label>

    <label>Year
        <input type="text" name ="year">
    </label>

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

""" 

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(form)

    def post(self):

        user_month = verify_date.valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = verify_date.valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = verify_date.valid_year(self.request.get('year'))


        # Test: always prints what was actually entered in the field, 
        # as expected, even if it's gibberish
        self.response.out.write(self.request.get('month'))

        # Should return the month entered (capitalized by verify_date.valid_day)
        # Prints December, regardless of what's entered 
        self.response.out.write(user_month)

        # As expected, prints the entered day if in range. Reloads form otherwise
        self.response.out.write(user_day)

        # As expected, prints the entered day if in range. Reloads form otherwise
        self.response.out.write(user_year)

        if not(user_month and user_year and user_day):
            self.response.out.write(form)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Thanks for the validation!")

        # Test: prints the entered month, even if gibberish
        self.response.out.write(self.request.get('month'))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

```
# verify_date.py

def valid_month(month):
    months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
    months = [month.lower() for month in months]
    month = month.lower()

    if month in months:
        month = month[0].upper() + month[1::]
    else:
        print 'Sorry, that is a not a valid month.'
        month = None
    return month

def valid_day(day):
    if day.isdigit() and int(day) < 32 and int(day) > 0:
        day = int(day)
    else:
        day = None
    return day

def valid_year(year):
    if year.isdigit() and int(year) < 2021 and int(year) > 1899:
        year = int(year)
    else:
        year = None
    return year
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using python 2.x? I think your issue is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199355/2074794

In python 2, the `month` variable in your list comprehension overrides the `month` arg passed to your function. So after the following line is executed, `month` holds the value of the last item in your `months` list, i.e. `December`:

`months = [month.lower() for month in months]`

You can use a different variable name there to avoid conflict:

`months = [m.lower() for m in months]`

Comment: It worked - thank you so, so much! I had no idea about this. I'll have to read more about it.