# Python 3 2-D list initialization breaks in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm trying to initialize a 2-D list using list comprehensions, but I'm seeing different results in Python 2 vs. Python 3 and I have no idea why.  Sample code (the `import` is just so I can use v3 print statements in v2):

```
from __future__ import print_function
ROW = 3
COL = 3

myList = [0 for i in range(ROW)]
#print('myList1 =', myList, 'len =', len(myList))
      
for i in range(len(myList)):
    #print('i =', i)
    myList[i] = [-1 for i in range(COL)]

#myList[0] = [-1 for i in range(COL)]

print('myList2 =', myList)
```

Python 3 output: `myList2 = [[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]`

Python 2 output: `myList2 = [0, 0, [-1, -1, -1]]`

The Python 3 behavior is what I would expect, and the commented out print statements are what I used to confirm that everything between the two up until the `myList[i]` assignment is the same.  If I manually do, e.g., `myList[0] =...` outside of the for loop it updates that element as expected.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `i` twice within the same for loop, once in the list-comprehension and once as a run variable for the outer for-loop. As detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199344/5012099), variables used in a list comprehension "leak" into the surrounding scope in python 2x. So your for loop processes like this:

1. Set `i=0`, from the for loop:

- List comprehension generates list of `-1`'s and sets `i=2`
- `myList[i] =` is actually  `myList[2] =`

2. Set `i=1`, from the for loop:

- List comprehension generates list of `-1`'s and sets `i=2`
- `myList[i] =` is actually  `myList[2] =`

3. Set `i=2`, from the for loop:

- List comprehension generates list of `-1`'s and sets `i=2`
- `myList[i] =` is actually  `myList[2] =`

Which generates the list `[0, 0, [-1, -1, -1]]`, because we only ever changed `myList[2]`

The simplest fix is to use different variables, i.e j in one place:

```
from __future__ import print_function

ROW = 3
COL = 3

myList = [0 for i in range(ROW)]

for i in range(len(myList)):
    #Use j for the list comprehension
    myList[i] = [-1 for j in range(COL)]

print('myList2 =', myList)
```

Comment: I originally accepted the answer before I tried it.  Using `mylist[j]` just causes the same problem, but `mylist[i] = [-1 for j in range(COL)]` seems to do the trick.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo, fixed it