# lambda in python reference mind puzzle

Tags: python, reference, lambda

Consider this example

```
def dump(value):
    print value

items = []    
for i in range(0, 2):
    items.append(lambda: dump(i))

for item in items:
    item()
```

output:

```
1
1
```

how can i get:

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a parameter with a default value on the lambda:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    items.append(lambda i=i: dump(i))
```

This works because the default value is evaluated when the function is defined, not when it is called.

Comment: man, you are smart. This was example but you found workaround, the point was how to eval that reference on lambda definition. Is there a way for doing that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    items.append(lambda i=i: dump(i))
```

to capture the current value of `i`

This works because default parameter values are evaluated at function creation time, and `i` is not the external variable, but a function parameter that will have the value you want as default.

A more detailed explanation can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036144/63011).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can also do:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    items.append((lambda i: lambda: dump(i))(i))
```

Comment: I feel this answer is the least hacky, even though it's more verbose than the default value answer.

Answer (score 0):

The output value is the value of i at the evaluation of the function, not at its declaration. That's why you don't get the desired result.