# how to pass nested function as an argument

Tags: python, function, nested

Lets say we have functions in python:

```
def _abs(iterable):   #cause its normally for one element only
    return [abs(i) for i in iterable]

def A(list, foo):
    return foo(list)

list = [2,3,-5]
print( A(list,foo=sum) )

>> 0
```

while I may pass `foo=sum` to A, I am looking for an elegant way to pass something like `foo=sum(_abs)` to perform `sum(_abs(list))`.

The only way I see it now is to send a list of functions `[sum, _abs]` and apply them in order. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you asking about function *composition* (rather than nesting) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739290/composing-functions-in-python

Comment: What you are describing is *"function composition"*. If you want to do this kind of functional-style programming, consider using a library dedicated to the purpose: http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=compos#toolz.functoolz.compose. Or just try `foo=lambda l: sum(map(abs, l))`.

Comment: As a side note, it's usually recommend to return a generator instead of a list, for your `_abs` it would be: `return (abs(i) for  in iterable)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's an excellent solution, and exactly what I've been looking for.
MarkusMeskanen why is so?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen or `map(abs, iterable)` if they're using 3.x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or, to compose more generally (i.e. with an arbitrary number of argument functions):

```
from functools import partial, reduce

def compose(*funcs):
    return partial(reduce, lambda x, f: f(x), reversed(funcs))
```

*(see the docs on [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) - note you don't need to import `reduce` in Python 2.x)*

Then:

```
>>> compose(sum, _abs)([2, 3, -5])
10
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make an explicit compose function

```
>>> def compose(f, g):
...   return lambda x: f(g(x))
...
```

Then use it

```
>>> A(list, compose(sum, _abs))
10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def compose(funcs, funcargs):
    for func in reversed(funcs):
        funcargs = func(funcargs)
    return funcargs
```

Comment: This applies them in the wrong (or, at least, *unconventional*) order.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I will modify my answer.