# How to compose a list of functions to a callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-composition

I have a simple source.

```
def h(x):
    return x + 1

def m(x):
    return x + 2

def n(x):
    return x * 10

def function_aggregator(fun_list, num):
    return_fun = None
    for fun in fun_list[::-1]:
        if return_fun:
            return_fun = fun(return_fun)
        else:
            return_fun = fun(num)
    return return_fun

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = [h, m, n]
    y = function_aggregator(lst, 4)
    print(y)
```

Is there any way to make the `function_aggregator` method receive just the list and return a callable the will be the same as `h(m(n(<any_number>))`

Comment: Maybe I should rewrite the n, m, h methods in some way?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739439

Comment: By the way, your `function_aggregator()` has an error: in your example, it's returning `n(m(h(4))) == 70`, not `h(m(n(4))) == 43`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is pretty close. The exact answer is:

```
def function_aggregator(fun_list):
    def wrapper(arg):
        for fun in reversed(fun_list):
            arg = fun(arg)
        return arg
    return wrapper


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = [g, f, n, m, h]
    p = function_aggregator(lst)
    x = 3
    print("p(x): {}".format(p(x)))
```

Thanks to [Zero Piraeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014938/zero-piraeus) commet

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using closure:

```
def function_aggregator(*func_list):
    def aggregate(num):
        for func in reversed(func_list):
            num = func(num)
        return num
    return aggregate

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunc = function_aggregator(h, m, n)
    print(myfunc(4))
```

## Notes

- `function_aggregator` now takes an arbitrary number of functions
- Inside, it defines another function, `aggregate`, this is the *callable* you are talking about.
- `function_aggregator` returns that *callable*, AKA `aggregate` to the caller
- The caller then give it a name, `myfunc` in this case
- From then on, we can treat `myfunc` as a function which takes 1 argument and return something