# Commands with multiple common options going into one argument using custom decorator

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, python-click

I would like to make a module that makes it very simple to build click commands that share a lot of options. Those options would be distilled into a single object that is passed into the command. As an illustrative example:

```
from magic import magic_command
import click

@magic_command('Colored')
@click.option('--color')
def cmd(magic, color):
    pass
```

The total command would then have many `--magic-...` options that go into the `magic` object passed into `cmd`. I was able to achieve that using the following:

```
def magic_command(name):
    def decorator(func):
        @click.option('--magic-foo')
        @click.option('--magic-bar')
        def wrapper(magic_foo, magic_bar, **kwargs):
            print(f'initializing Magic with {magic_foo} and {magic_bar}')
            magic = Magic(magic_foo, magic_bar)
            func(magic, **kwargs)

        try:
            wrapper.__click_params__.extend(func.__click_params__)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        return click.command(f'{name}-Magic')(wrapper)
    return decorator
```

However, messing with the `__click_params__` doesn't seem particularly clean.

The question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061342/is-it-possible-to-reuse-python-click-option-decorators-for-multiple-commands), however this approach does not allow me to condense the many magic options into a magic object.

To elaborate, with this approach I would have to do

```
@magic_command('Colored')
@click.option('--color')
def cmd(magic_foo, magic_bar, color):
    magic = Magic(magic_foo, magic_bar)
    pass
```

But that means the custom code needs to be aware what magic options there are and how to construct the magic. I guess that can be simplified using `**kwargs` but still - ideally I'd like to just have a ready `magic` object passed to `cmd`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can distill multiple options into a single object quite simply by constructing a decorator like:

#### Code:

```
def magic_options(func):
    @click.option('--magic-bar')
    @click.option('--magic-foo')
    def distill_magic(magic_foo, magic_bar, **kwargs):
        kwargs['magic'] = Magic(magic_foo, magic_bar)
        func(**kwargs)

    return distill_magic
```

#### Using the decorator

You can then apply the decorator to the command function like:

```
@click.command('Colored-Magic')
@click.option('--color')
@magic_options
def cli(magic, color):
    ...
```

It needs to be applied to the bare function.  This is because the function returned by `click.option` has been modified by the click framework and it won't work the way you expected.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.command('Colored-Magic')
@click.option('--color')
@magic_options
def cli(magic, color):
    click.echo(str(magic))
    click.echo(color)


class Magic(object):
    def __init__(self, magic_foo, magic_bar):
        self.magic_foo = magic_foo
        self.magic_bar = magic_bar

    def __str__(self):
        return "foo: {}  bar: {}".format(self.magic_foo, self.magic_bar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '--magic-foo fooby --magic-bar barbecue',
        '--magic-foo fooby',
        '--magic-bar barbecue',
        '',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> --magic-foo fooby --magic-bar barbecue
foo: fooby  bar: barbecue

-----------
> --magic-foo fooby
foo: fooby  bar: None

-----------
> --magic-bar barbecue
foo: None  bar: barbecue

-----------
> 
foo: None  bar: None

-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --color TEXT
  --magic-bar TEXT
  --magic-foo TEXT
  --help            Show this message and exit.
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing some "magic attrs" of a function in a decorator is perfectly normal:
[`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) does just that. So you can:

1. Use `@wraps`
2. Use `@click.option` "after" `@wraps`
3. define magic options as a list, and parse args/kwargs using values in that list.

```py
from functools import wraps, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS

DEFAULT_MAGIC_OPTIONS = ('--magic-foo', '--magic-bar')


def magic_command(name, magic_options=DEFAULT_MAGIC_OPTIONS):
    magic_options = magic_options or []
    magic_kwarg_names = [opt.split('--', 1)[1].replace('-', '_') for opt in magic_options]

    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS+('__click_params__', ))
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            num_used_magic_args = min(len(magic_kwarg_names), len(args))

            magic_args = args[:num_used_magic_args]

            # If you want magic options to be "args only", then:
            # * you can raise TypeError if num_used_magic_args != len(magic_kwarg_names)
            # * you should not calculate `magic_kwargs`
            magic_kwargs = {}
            for kwarg_name in magic_kwarg_names[num_used_magic_args:]:
                if kwarg_name in kwargs:
                    magic_kwargs[kwarg_name] = kwargs.pop(kwarg_name)

            print(f'Initializing Magic with args={magic_args}, kwargs={magic_kwargs}')
            magic = Magic(*magic_args, **magic_kwargs)
            return func(magic, *args[num_used_magic_args:], **kwargs)

        for magic_option in magic_options[::-1]:  # Reverse order, to have proper positional arguments
            wrapper = click.option(magic_option)(wrapper)

        return click.command(f'{name}-Magic')(wrapper)

    return decorator
```

Usage:

```py
@magic_command('Colored')
@click.option('--color')  # Note: wrapper will be properly updated 
# with this @click.option, but related argument will not be passed
# into `Magic(...)` initialization.
# If you want `color` to be passed into `Magic`: specify it as one 
# of the items in `magic_options` argument of magic_command decorator:
# `@magic_command('Colored', magic_options=DEFAULT_MAGIC_OPTIONS+('color', ))`
# AND remove it from function definition here (keep only `magic`)
def cmd(magic, color):
    assert isinstance(magic, Magic)
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to do what you want without using click internals but, there must be a way, right?

Anyway, here is a solution that makes use of another decorator. This one is put just above the function and its function is to group the `magic_*` parameters.

```
def magic_command(f):
    f = click.option('--magic-bar')(f)
    f = click.option('--magic-foo')(f)
    f = click.command()(f)
    return f

def group_magic_args(f):
    def new_f(magic_foo, magic_bar, *args, **kwargs):
        magic = Magic(magic_foo, magic_bar)
        f(magic=magic, *args, **kwargs)
    return new_f
```

You would use the new decorator like this:

```
@magic_command
@click.option('--color')
@group_magic_args
def cmd(magic, color):
    pass
```