# Decorating decorators and the Click python library

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-click

I am trying to use decorators with the Click framework to perform work common to multiple commands without using arguments in the root element of the group (see https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/295 for why). In short, something like this:

```py
@click.group()
def main():
  pass

@main.command()
@click.option('--argument-a')
@parse_config_file
@init_session
def do_something_in_session(argument_a, config, session):
   # code
   return
```

where the decorators also have arguments:

```py
def init_session(f):
  @wraps(f)
  @click.option('--argument-B')
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something with argument-B, and add session to list of arguments.
    del kwargs['argument-B']
    kwargs['session'] = session_created_above

    return f(*args,**kwargs)
  return wrapper

def parse_config_file(f):
  @wraps(f)
  @click.option('--argument-C')
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something with argument-C, and add config to list of arguments.
    del kwargs['argument-C']
    kwargs['config'] = config_parsed_above

    return f(*args,**kwargs)
  return wrapper
```

However, when running `do_something_in_session --help`, only the arguments of the decorator just above the function definition, in this case `@init_session`, are shown. Is there a way for me to decorate the decorators so that Click parses the arguments properly?

Comment: The decorators need to be applied to the bare function.  So you can not easily stack your custom decorators.

Comment: More explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56317633/7311767

Comment: So, from what I've read in the other thread, it should be possible if I could find way to update the proper `vars` that `@click.option` uses. From what I can see, `@click.option` adds a new `__click_params__` entry in the `__dict__` of the functions it wraps. I think I just have to make sure that my decorators propagate that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how this works in our codebase (using click 7.1.2).

```
def decorator_example(f):

    @pass_context
    @click.option("--testy")
    def wrapper(ctx, *args, testy, **kwargs):
        # Do stuff with testy here
        testy = f"pre{testy}"
    
    # Think this is the bit that allows click to be aware of options defined on the wrapper
    return ctx.invoke(wrapped_function, *args, testy=testy, **kwargs)

# Using functools to update the wrapper as required - think this is the same as @wraps(f)?
return update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped_function)
```

Comment: This is nominally what the click documentation recommends https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/#decorating-commands