# create structured data directly from python @click?

Tags: python, python-click

As discussed [one may reuse python click decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061342/is-it-possible-to-reuse-python-click-option-decorators-for-multiple-commands/67740068#67740068) from several scripts easily.
However, with growing number of parameters

- the main function parameter list gets crowded and voids pylint `too-many-arguments`
- the code processing these many parameters end up in WET programming
- if one has several scripts using these parameters, even multiple places of similar code have to be maintained

Hence, is there a way to create a class objects directly in the decorators to group parameters?

so, from a decorator function like this:

```py
def common_options(mydefault=True):
    def inner_func(function):
        function = click.option('--unique-flag-1', is_flag=True)(function)
        function = click.option('--bar', is_flag=True)(function)
        function = click.option('--foo', is_flag=True, default=mydefault)(function)
        return function
    return inner_func
```

directly emit a class like this:

```py
class CommonOptions:
    def __init__(unique_flag_1, bar, foo):
        self.unique_flag_1 = ....
```

could be directly emitted to

```py
@click.command
@common_options()
def main(common_options: CommonOptions):
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `**kwargs` in a `click` command, so you could write something like:

```
import click
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class CommonOptions:
    unique_flag_1: bool
    bar: bool
    foo: bool


def common_options(mydefault=True):
    def inner_func(function):
        function = click.option("--unique-flag-1", is_flag=True)(function)
        function = click.option("--bar", is_flag=True)(function)
        function = click.option("--foo", is_flag=True, default=mydefault)(function)
        return function

    return inner_func


@click.command()
@common_options()
def main(**kwargs):
    options = CommonOptions(**kwargs)
    print(options)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

W/r/t to your comment, if we borrow an idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55096964/147356) we can write such that we can have multiple option groups, but for each group we just pass all of `**kwargs` and let the receiver sort it out:

```
import click

from dataclasses import dataclass


class OptionGroup:
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, **options):
        return cls(
            **{k: v for k, v in options.items() if k in cls.__dataclass_fields__}
        )


@dataclass
class OptionGroup1(OptionGroup):
    unique_flag_1: bool
    bar: bool
    foo: bool


@dataclass
class OptionGroup2(OptionGroup):
    count: int
    size: int


def option_group_1(mydefault=True):
    def _(function):
        function = click.option("--unique-flag-1", is_flag=True)(function)
        function = click.option("--bar", is_flag=True)(function)
        function = click.option("--foo", is_flag=True, default=mydefault)(function)
        return function

    return _


def option_group_2():
    def _(function):
        function = click.option("--count", type=int)(function)
        function = click.option("--size", type=int)(function)
        return function

    return _


@click.command()
@option_group_2()
@option_group_1()
def main(**kwargs):
    o1 = OptionGroup1.from_dict(**kwargs)
    o2 = OptionGroup2.from_dict(**kwargs)
    print("group1:", o1)
    print("group2:", o2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Some example output:

```
$ python example.py
group1: OptionGroup1(unique_flag_1=False, bar=False, foo=True)
group2: OptionGroup2(count=None, size=None)
$ python example.py --count=3 --bar
group1: OptionGroup1(unique_flag_1=False, bar=True, foo=True)
group2: OptionGroup2(count=3, size=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your sugestion! however, since I've got several param groups and several of these argument containers, it seems I must put kwargs into them, and from there only pick the ones relevant to this very object? or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I've updated the answer to handle the situation you're asking about (if I understood the comment correctly).

Comment: You missed that count and size are not required and have no default. Your dataclass will recieve None unexpectedly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I got so frustrated with the complexity involved in managing kwargs, I created [dataclass-click](https://github.com/couling/dataclass-click) as a bolt-on to Click that uses [PEP 593 Anotated](https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/).  Just:

```
pip install dataclass-click
```

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Annotated

import click
from dataclass_click import dataclass_click, option


@dataclass
class OptionGroup1:
    unique_flag_1: Annotated[bool, option("--unique_flag-1", is_flag=True)]
    bar: Annotated[bool, option("--bar", is_flag=True)]
    foo: Annotated[bool, option("--foo", is_flag=True, default=True)]


@dataclass
class OptionGroup2:
    # Inferences are cool
    # @click.option("--count", type=click.INT, required=False)
    count: Annotated[int | None, option()]
    # @click.option("--size", type=click.INT, required=True)
    size: Annotated[int, option()]


@click.command()
@dataclass_click(OptionGroup1, kw_name="o1")
@dataclass_click(OptionGroup2, kw_name="o2")
def main(o1: OptionGroup1, o2: OptionGroup2):
    print("group1:", o1)
    print("group2:", o2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This also supports inheritence.  Whether you use two dataclasses or one inheriting from another would depend on the structure of your code.