# TypeError: descriptor 'upper' requires a 'str' object but received a 'function' (beginner)

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass two functions as parameters, but i have an error with functions `str.upper` and `str.strip`. I can't figure what i'm doing wrong?

```
def normalize_text(func1, func2):
    return func2(func1)


def my_strip(s):
    return str.strip(s)


def my_upper(s):
    return str.upper(s)


def test():
    if(normalize_text(my_strip, my_upper)(' foo ') == 'FOO'):
        print('Success')


test()
```

Running code like this `python main.py`

... and then I face an error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'upper' requires a 'str' object but received a 'function'
```

Comment: You are passing a function as parameter in my_upper() function instead of a string. Can you see that str.upper(s) needs a string instead of a function.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739290/composing-functions-in-python for more complicated cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function should work along these lines:

```
def normalize_text(func1, func2):
    def func3(s):
        return func2(func1(s))
    return func3
```

Both `func1`and `func2` take a string as input and return a string. Hence, One should process the output of the other when chained together, not the function itself.

Comment: I can't check this solution about passing two functions as parameters and return third while i have an issue with functions `str.upper` and `str.strip`.

Comment: Your problem comes form how you call the two in your `normalize_text`. Your other two functions are fine on their own.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `func2` to `func1`, but `func1` expects a string as its argument, so you need to pass the result of calling `func2` on something.

`normalize_text` can return a lambda that calls the two functions on an input parameter.

```
def normalize_text(func1, func2):
    return lambda s: func1(func2(s))
```

Comment: Yes, it works like previous solution but much shorter due to use of lambda expression, thank you very much.