# Function calling functions

Tags: python, functional-programming

Create a function that takes any number of functions as positional arguments.  The function returns execution of function-arguments one by one. See example for better understanding (Let's call this function ***chain***).

```
my_func = chain(lambda x: x + 2, lambda x: (x/4, x//4))
my_func(37)
```

It should return

```
(9.75, 9)
```

I tried to do something like:

```
def chain(x,*args):
    for arg in args:
        arg(x)
```

It is not working. Can't understand how to take a non function argument to this function (in example above 37).

Comment: `chain` _shouldn't_ take a non-function argument - it _returns_ a function that does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composing functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739290/composing-functions-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
def chain(*funcs):
    def chained(*args, **kwargs):
        return tuple(func(*args, **kwargs) for func in funcs)
    return chained

my_func = chain(lambda x: x + 2, lambda x: (x/4, x//4))
print(my_func(37))
```

Output:

```
(39, (9.25, 9))
```