# Tkinter Dynamically Created Buttons Presenting Wrong Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

Here's some (python 3) code:

```
from tkinter import *

def makeButtons():
    global mainFrame
    listy = ["a", "b", "c"]
    dicty = {"a":["1", "2", "3"], "b":["4", "5", "6", "7"], "c":["8", "9"]}
    buttons = []
    for x, item in enumerate(listy):
        for y, value in enumerate(dicty[item]):
            btn=Button(mainFrame, text=value)
            btn.grid(column=x, row=y)
            buttons.append(btn)
    for i, but in enumerate(buttons):
        text = buttons[i]["text"]
        but.config(command=lambda *a: vocabMode(i, text))

def vocabMode(i, text):
    print(i, text)

root = Tk()
mainFrame = Frame(root)
mainFrame.grid(column=1, row=2)
makeButtons()
root.mainloop()
```

Go ahead, run it. It works. Except for one small thing.

I'm expecting it to print the text of the label. But no matter what I try, it always prints the value of the last button created. I can't find a solution anywhere when I want it to print its own value.
Thanks for the help.

Edit: It has been claimed that this is a duplicate of [Generating functions inside loop with lambda expression in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841268/generating-functions-inside-loop-with-lambda-expression-in-python). I'm not sure how. The answers there don't resolve my issues, or if they do, the relationship is too abstract for me to understand.

Comment: I acknowledge some goofiness in the code. They are relics from creating the snippette.

Comment: Your problem here and the dupe target are same. If those answers didn't explained enough, going through _linked_ questions might help as well. And for the solution, just add default values to your lambda. `command= lambda i=i, text=text: vocabMode(i, text)`

Comment: While maybe not the best choice of a duplicate, this question is a duplicate of many, many questions. This sort of thing gets asked all the time. Don't look at the accepted answer to that question, look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1841368/7432 or maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33984811/7432 or maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7546960/7432 or maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2295368/7432

Comment: "It has been claimed that this is a duplicate of Generating functions inside loop with lambda expression in python. I'm not sure how." In this case, `for i, but in enumerate(buttons):` is the loop, and `lambda *a: vocabMode(i, text)` is the lambda expression that generates functions. The problem occurs, as explained there and in many other places, because the lambda uses `i`, which comes from the iteration. The solution is to bind it explicitly, as described in those answers, using the techniques shown there.