# Python - appending a function to a list

Tags: python, list, function, lambda, append

I want to create a list that contains the monomials up to degree *n*

```
basis = [lambda x:x**i for i in range(0,n+1)]
```

This however creates a list of *n* functions, but all the same one (of degree *n*) and not of degree 0,1,2,...*n*

I tried without list comprehension as well:

```
basis = []
for i in range(0,n+1):
    basis.append(lambda x:x**i)
```

but with the same result. Substituting the lambda function by a classic function definition also did not fix it.

---

I checked [Python lambdas and scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924214/python-lambdas-and-scoping), but that did not help, since I don't want to store function values, but the function itself. For example, I want to be able to call

```
basis[0](34)
```

and this should return

```
1
```

Comment: you can do this with `partial` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) but you will need a *proper* function declaration

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comments, take a look at [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
def f(x, n):
    return x**n

basis = [partial(f, n=i) for i in range(10)]
print(basis[0](34))  # 1
```

Answer (score -1):

This entry sums it up perfectly

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures :

> ... you can create a closure that binds immediately to its arguments by using a default arg like so:
>
> ```
> def create_multipliers():
>       return [lambda x, i=i : i * x for i in range(5)]
> ```

You code would become:

```
basis = [lambda x,i=i:x**i for i in range(0,n+1)]
```

This is a bit of a hacky solution, but works. I still highly recommend to read the link provided as the 3 points that are made there are usual errors when you are new to Python.

Comment: It seams this is a link only answer .

Comment: Link-only answers are not appreciated. Copy the relevant text to the answer, and use the link for supporting details.