# Where to look for parameter that was just returned by signal?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

QTabWidget has signal [currentChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtabwidget.html#currentChanged). And it returns index of current tab.
But how can I get this parameter in such expression:

```
tabs.currentChanged.connect(lambda: foo());

def foo(index):
    ...
```

Where should I look for this parameter that was just returned?

Comment: An answer of mine to a previous question of yours would be helpful:
[Previous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159021/lambda-i-i-fooi-in-for-loop-not-working/6162445#6162445)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals don't "return" anything. They can have parameters though, which is the case for `currentIndex`. If you want that argument passed to your function, you should try:

```
tabs.currentChanged.connect(lambda index: foo(index));
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Why you say that it is not returned? Signal returns (emit, pass, send) parameter to slot. Who else if not signal did it?

Comment: A signal can pass/emit/send values to a slot. It does not return values to it. That's just vocabulary/terminology.

Comment: Is there any good reason to use the lambda here? Can't you just do `tabs.currentChanged.connect(foo)`? Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @Whatang: I have no idea, I'm not really familiar with python.