# Build dynamic list of parameterized functions in python

Tags: python, lambda

Using [fmin_slsqp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp), I have to provide

> ```
> ieqcons : list, optional
>
> A list of functions of length n such that ieqcons[j](x,*args) >= 0.0 in a successfully optimized problem.
> ```

Since my problem is quite large, the simple option of writing them explicitly does not work.

```
def f1(x,arg1,arg2):
     ...
def f2(x,arg1,arg2):
     ...
...

list_func = [f1,f2,...]
```

There is this question which addresses [dynamic and anonymous functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303248/true-dynamic-and-anonymous-functions-possible-in-python) and most of the answer go around parsing the code as a string, which seems totally unnecessary and complicates passing of arguments to the function.

The nature of  the constrains list is that a single parameter (the index e.g.) can uniquely identify the function, but all the functions in the list receive the same arguments and it is impossible to make a distinction based on passed arguments.

A construction of this form would be sufficient and painless

```
def f(x,arg1,arg2,i):
   # return value based on i
   # e.g. # for constrain of form x[i]>=arg1[i] the funct is:
   #        return x[i]-arg1[i]

i = 1
f1 = lambda x,arg1,arg2 : f(x,arg1,arg2,i)
i = 2
f2 = lambda x,arg1,arg2 : f(x,arg1,arg2,i)
```

Calling `f1` and `f2` returns the same functions for `i=2`

However I can not find a solution to make `i` final in the function definition or restrict its scope, visibility to a particular lambda function.

As a remark, `i` has to remain a variable since the final solution would look like

```
list_f =[]
for i in range(0,num_cons):
    list_f.append(lambda x,arg1,arg2 : f(x,arg1,arg2,i))
```

How can I solve this issue or is there a more simpler and clever way of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you can solve it using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

list_f = [partial(f, i=i) for i in range(0, num_cons)]
```

You can find more information on `lambda` vs `partial` here:

- [Python: Why is functools.partial necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary)

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working as expected is when you write a lambda expression, it does not call the function; it is called when you evaluate the expression.

So, when you evaluate it, the value of `i` is 2, hence the same results.

I believe what you need is `functools.partial`, like this:

```
from functools import partial

func_call_map = {i: partial(f, i=i) for i in [some range]}

# Get result for i = 4
ret_value = func_call_map[4](other, args, here)
```

Comment: Thank you. It totally makes sense the behaviour now and `partial` does the job

Answer (score 1):

Following @alecxe link on [Python: Why is functools.partial necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary) and the explanation provided in the comments of one of the answers, to avoid the late binding (lazy evaluation) explained by @BurhanKhalid, the code would need to be changed as follows

```
i = 1
f1 = lambda x,arg1,arg2,n_i=i : f(x,arg1,arg2,n_i)
i = 2
f2 = lambda x,arg1,arg2,n_i=i : f(x,arg1,arg2,n_i)
```

But using `functions.partial` provides a more elegant solution.