# Python version issue when using types.FunctionType

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, types

I have a problem with code snippet founded on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10303539/4113228

When I try to compile:

```
import types
dynf = types.FunctionType(compile('print("wow")', 'dyn.py', 'exec'), {})
dynf()
```

in file test.py using python2.7, everything working fine,
but when I try with python3.5 I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    dynf()
  File "dyn.py", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'print' is not defined
```

I'm new in python coding and I completly get stuck at this.. Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing an empty dict as `globals` - because of this, the compiled code can't access global variables *or* builtins.

To allow access to builtin functions, use

```
import builtins
dynf = types.FunctionType(compile('print("wow")', 'dyn.py', 'exec'), {'__builtins__':builtins})
```