# Unexpected behaviour with lambda function in an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I'm creating an array of lambda function that way (shift by n bits over a 16 bits representation but the problem is independent of the function role):

```
>>> lshifting=[lambda x:(x<<y) & 65535 for y in range(0,16)]
```

I'm expecting each lambda to use the value y had when the function was instanciated.

If I check, each lambda is a different object in memory:

```
>>> print (lshifting)
[<function <lambda> at 0x7f11b632fde8>, <function <lambda> at 0x7f11b632fe60>, <function <lambda> at 0x7f11b632fed8>,....
```

However, the behaviour is not what I expect:

```
>>> [x(1) for x in lshifting]
[32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768, 32768]

>>> [(1<<y) & 65535 for y in range(0,16)]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768]
```

I'm obviously expecting both result to be identical while all lambdas seems to have been created with a reference to the temporary `y` variable and then, when used, take the last known value of this variable.

I got 2 questions:

- is this an expected behaviour ?
- what is the pythonic way to instanciate functions dynamically? (typical example is [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying))

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/lexical-closures-in-python

Comment: One common way to deal with this is shown in the accepted answer in my 1st link: provide `y` as a default keyword arg, eg `lambda x,y=y:(x<<y) & 65535`, since default args are set when the function is created (whether it's a normal `def`-style function or a `lambda`).

Comment: I ended up writing a wrapper class and using it as a functor, easier to read. Nasty one though :-/