# Dynamically add function to a module with introspection in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list with function names, add them as functions to a module so that they can be invoked from the module using the function name as an argument.

```
from package import module_name

Functions = [ 'Add', 'Subtract' ]

for function in Functions:
  def api_endpoint(*args):
    return module_name.api(function, *args)

  setattr(module_name, function, api_endpoint)
```

I want to be able to call `module_name.Add(arg1, arg2)` and invoke `module_name.api('Add', arg1, arg2)`.

How can I pass on this sort of introspection and dynamically add a function to a module? I tried setting it up this way, but any invocation of module_name.Add always invokes the last item in Functions (e.g. Subtract), which is incorrect.

I tried making api_endpoint a Class which overrides `__new__`, but that did not help, since if `__new__` does not return an instance of the class being created, `__init__` is never invoked and I can't get instance variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
from TestPackage import TestModule

Functions = [ 'Add', 'Subtract' ]

for function in Functions:
    p = partial(TestModule.api, function)
    setattr(TestModule, function, p)


TestModule.Add(1,2)         # Add 1 2
TestModule.Subtract(3,4)    # Subtract 3 4
```

Where TestModule contains simply:

```
def api(func, *args):
    print(func, *args)
```

Or, leveraging how arguments are evaluated:

```
from TestPackage import TestModule

functions = [ 'Add', 'Subtract' ]

for fn in functions:
    def api_endpoint(*args, fn=fn):               # Added 'fn=fn'
        return TestModule.api(fn, *args)

    setattr(TestModule, fn, api_endpoint)


TestModule.Add(1,2)         # Add 1 2
TestModule.Subtract(3,4)    # Subtract 3 4
```

Or, using closures (not a huge fan of this, especially compared to the first):

```
from TestPackage import TestModule

functions = [ 'Add', 'Subtract' ]

for fn in functions:
    def bind_fn(fn):
        def api_endpoint(*args):
            return TestModule.api(fn, *args)

        return api_endpoint

    setattr(TestModule, fn, bind_fn(fn))


TestModule.Add(1,2)         # Add 1 2
TestModule.Subtract(3,4)    # Subtract 3 4
```

Edit: The reason your approach was using "Subtract" as the func being passed (for both invocations) is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452819/736937).

Comment: I really like the use of the default argument evaluation. I don't have to import anything else. Why does this work, but passing the function its self doesn't?

Comment: In your case, when you call `TestModule.Add`, it calls `api_endpoint` which ***then*** looks up `fn` in the scope it was defined in.  But `fn` has since changed.  I added a third option to the answer which illustrates how you can use a closure to "localize" the lookup.  In the third option, `fn` is still looked up, but now looked up in the local scope of the `bind_fn` function and that *doesn't* change during the loop.  The second option is similar, in that default arguments are evaluated once, when the function definition is evaluated.  So `fn` is looked up locally, inside `api_endpoint`.