# How to use multi-threading in inference when there are more than 1 GPUs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Update**: solved by including `x`, `y`, and `sess` into the arguments of the worker.

**Original question**:

I have two GPUs and plan to create one thread for one GPU to achieve (data) parallelism. My attempt:

```
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = ['/device:GPU:0', '/device:GPU:1']
n_devices = len(gpus)
graphs = []

for gpu in gpus:
    with tf.device(gpu):
        with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_def_pb_path, "rb") as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        for node in graph_def.node:
            node.device = gpu
        with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
            graphs.append(g)

xs = [g.get_tensor_by_name(<input_tensor_name>) for g in graphs]
ys = [g.get_tensor_by_name(<output_tensor_name>) for g in graphs]
sessions = [tf.Session(graph=g, 
    config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) for g in graphs]
workers = [lambda x_val: sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: x_val}) 
    for sess, x, y in zip(sessions, xs, ys)]
n_devices = len(graphs)
results = []
threads = [None] * n_devices

for i, image in enumerate(data):
    t_idx = i % n_devices
    thread = threads[t_idx]
    if thread is not None:
        output = thread.join()
        results.append(output)

    # see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6893968/688080
    thread = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=workers[t_idx], args=(image,))

    thread.start()
    threads[t_idx] = thread

for thread in threads:
    output = thread.join()
    results.append(output)

for sess in sessions:
    sess.close()
```

However, it seems only the last device is doing the job. And if I change the code to single-threaded as below, I can see the GPUs are occupied alternatingly, which indicates the devices are assigned correctly:

```
# after import the graph into the devices
# x: input tensor, y: output tensor
sessions = [tf.Session(graph=g, 
    config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) for g in graphs]
result = [None] * len(data)
for i, image in enumerate(data):
    sess = sessions[i % n_devices]
    result[i] = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: image})
```

So how to correct the code or what is the correct way to do data parallelism in inference stage for freezed graph?

Comment: You already fixed or still need help?

Comment: @DavidNogueira Ah, the problem is from the lambda binding -- quite a common gotchas in Python (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/10452770/688080). So just put all the used variables inside lambda into its argument list.

Comment: But for multi-threading usage, when using just one model (multiple inferences at the same time), the same g = tf.Graph() can be used, right?
g = tf.Graph()   #once\n
# and then, inside thread worker code:\n
with g.as_default():\n
    ...

Comment: I realize this was a long time ago, but were you able to get the multi-threading inference to work successfully? So the inferences all happen in parallel?

Comment: It's not clear what's going on with this question. Please read [mre] and clearly state a problem, if there is one. Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; please don't "update" to indicate fixes. If the problem was resolved, the question still stands; if not, there is potentially a **new question**.