# Force global variable in function definition be treated like a literal

Tags: python

Say I want to create a list of 5 functions, where the i-th function just adds i to the argument. The naive code

```
L = []
for i in range(5):
    def f(z):
        return z+i
    L.append(f)
```

apparently does not work: `print([f(0) for f in L])` yields `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]`. Similarly,

```
L = [lambda z: z+i for i in range(5)]
```

does not work either. The value of i at the time when the function is defined is not fixed to f. A clumsy hack is

```
tmp = ["lambda z:z+{}".format(i) for i in range(5)]
L = eval("[" + ",".join(tmp) + "]")
```

But I'm sure that there is a clean solution! Which is it?

Comment: To create closures that use a variable (like `i`) you need to bind it during definition time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_func(i):
    return lambda z: z + i

L = [get_func(i) for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to an answer to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values) (thanks to rdas for the link in the comments), default arguments are evaluated when a function is created, not when it is called. So this alternative to Peter Collingridge's suggestion works too:

```
L = []
for i in range(5):
    def f(z, i=i):
        return z+i
    L.append(f)
```

or

```
L = [lambda z, i=i: z+i for i in range(5)]
```