# Best way to copy a function parameter and change the copy, when the parameter is an object attribute? [Python]

Tags: python, oop, deep-copy

Noticed that when a passed parameter is an object, making a copy of the parameter and changing the copy attribute's value also changes the original attribute's value (Shallow Copy). However, when the passed object is a simple variable, creating and changing the copy's value does not change the original (Deep Copy).

#### Example:

**1. Variable passed as argument**

```
def increment(x):
    y = x
    y += 1
    print(f'{x=}, {y=}')
increment(2)
```

```
Out: 
x=2, y=3
```

`x` did not change when it's copy `y` was incremented

**2. Object passed as argument**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val=0):
        self.val = val

def increment(x):
    y = x
    y.val += 1
    print(f'{x.val=}, {y.val=}')
increment(Node(2))
```

```
Out: 
x.val=3, y.val=3
```

`x.val` was also incremented when copy `y.val` was incremented.

What is the best (computationally time-efficient) way to go about creating a deep copy of the object? Can I write the class in a way such that I don't have to make any changes in the function code?

Comment: The answer to your second question is no. There's no way to make a class that can detect when it's being assigned to a new variable. Python simply doesn't support that.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452866).

Comment: @ManuelGarcía this doesn't have anything to do with lambdas, closures or late binding; but it *is* a common duplicate.

Comment: There isn't a difference between "objects" and "variables" here - you can't actually pass "variables"; you pass a **value** - which are the result of evaluating an **expression** (and a variable name by itself is one kind of expression). Values in Python are all objects. The difference here is between *reassigning* a name, versus *mutating the object* with that name. You can, of course, avoid the problem by making a copy. Please see the linked duplicate - `y = x` **does not copy, not even a shallow copy**. You may, however, not always need a deep copy. Your example only needs a shallow copy.