# Iteration in a for loop overwrites previously defined distinct dict keys when linking new keys to new lambda functions. Is this expected?

Tags: python, lambda

I am possibly very naive, but I find the following behaviour unexpected.

Introduction: I need a wrapper to address dynamically the methods of my own class, model. I am trying to use a dict to have a separate entry for each of a given number of members of the class that are dynamically requested. I link the dict keys to the chosen members iteratively and I find that the doc string is preserved, but the methods get overwritten by the last item in the iteration, despite their distinct keys. Here is a snippet where I reproduce the behaviour with numpy, in place of my own class.

```
import numpy as np
name = ["sin","cos"]

bnd = {}
print('Within the defining loop, it works!\n')
for nam in name:
    # useless indirect function (with doc string)
    # equivalent to sin(2*pi*x) 
    # or to cos(2*pi*x)
    bnd[nam] = lambda x, par: np.__getattribute__(nam)(x*par)
    bnd[nam].__doc__ = '"""'+nam+'"""'
    print('bnd doc in-loop: {} = {}'.format(nam,bnd[nam].__doc__))
    print('bnd method in-loop {}(0,2*pi) = {}'.format(nam,bnd[nam](0,2*np.pi)))

print('\n    However after the loop...')
print('bnd keys {}'.format(bnd.keys()))
print('\nfirst function doc: {}'.format(bnd["sin"].__doc__))
print('doc is preserved, but instead the method')
print('(should be sin(2 pi *0)) yields {}'.format(bnd["sin"](0,2*np.pi)))
print('\nsecond trial_function doc: {}'.format(bnd["cos"].__doc__))
print('doc is preserved, again, and this time the method')
print('(should be cos(2 pi *0)) yields  correctly {}'.format(bnd["cos"](0,2*np.pi)))
print('\nSummary: bnd[nam] gets overwritten by the last lambda definition in the loop. \n\nWhy????')
```

If you run the code you get the following

```
Within the defining loop, it works!

bnd doc in-loop: sin = """sin"""
bnd method in-loop sin(0,2*pi) = 0.0
bnd doc in-loop: cos = """cos"""
bnd method in-loop cos(0,2*pi) = 1.0

    However after the loop...
bnd keys dict_keys(['sin', 'cos'])

first function doc: """sin"""
doc is preserved, but instead the method
(should be sin(2 pi *0)) yields 1.0

second trial_function doc: """cos"""
doc is preserved, again, and this time the method
(should be cos(2 pi *0)) yields  correctly 1.0

Summary: bnd[nam] gets overwritten by the last lambda definition in the loop. 

Why????
```

which I hope is clarifying my question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you tag this with [python]!

Comment: I was pointed to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values by https://github.com/bonfus, which already contains an answer: in brief, I was overlooking that nam also is a lambda parameter, and, as such, it takes value at execution time, not at definition time. The link shows that ```bnd[nam] = lambda x, par, nam=nam: np.__getattribute__(nam)(x*par)``` does the trick. Added in the code as a comment now

Comment: Please don't answer your question inside the question itself. If you want, you are free to post an answer to your own question, but anyway this is a duplicate so please mark it as such

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate, but I must say it's one of the sneakiest problems I've seen in Python.  I wouldn't know how to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained.  There is only one variable `nam` in your function.  When you create the lambda, it doesn't capture the value of `nam` as it was when created the lambda.  Rather all the lambdas share the same `nam`, and it has whatever value it had at the end of the function.

There are several get arounds.  Essentially you need to capture `nam` as a variable.

The "official" way to do this is that you could just write:

```
   def attribute_getter(nam):
      return lambda x, par: np.__getattribute__(nam)(x*par)
   bind[nam] = attribute_getter(nam)
```

The quick and dirty solution is:

```
   bind[nam] = lambda x, par, nam=nam: np.__getattribute__(name)(x * par)
```

The variable `nam` is turned into an optional which is set to the current value of `nam`.

---

Edit:  Changed "program" to "function".