# At what moment are closure cells evaluated? Can lambas have closures?

Tags: python, lambda, closures

Consider the following code:

```
def A():
    l = list()
    for i in range(5):
        l.append(lambda: i)
    return l

for f in A():
    print( f() )
```

It prints out `4` five times, and I'm assuming it does that because the lambda function has taken the variable `i` through the outer scope of `A`, but right before the moment the variable became out of scope.

Then we have this code:

```
def B():
    l = list()
    for i in range(5):
        l.append((lambda i: lambda: i)(i))
    return l

for f in B():
    print( f() )
```

It prints out all numbers from 0 to 4 in order. I am assuming it does that because the variable `i` has been grabbed from the scope of the outer lambda which took it as a parameter, so the value has been assigned to the cell in the moment when that external lambda finished executing.

But what if `i` held a mutable object instead of an immutable `int`?

```
def C():
    l, i = list(), list()
    for r in range(5):
        i.append(r)
        l.append((lambda i: lambda: i)(i.copy()))
    return l

for f in C():
    print( f() )
```

It does print out the lists in order as expected, because I used the `list.copy()` method in the argument.

Now, is my understanding correct?

If so, then is there a more pythonic or simpler way to save in a closure cell either an immutable object (or a copy of a mutable object), at the exact moment I want to? In other words, is there a better way than the `(lambda i: lambda: i)(i)` latch I came up with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python lambda's binding to local values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values)

Comment: Closures capture variables, not values. A closure doesn't save the state of a variable at some particular time; it saves the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of late binding, try this code:

```
def bind(value):
  return lambda: value

def A():
    l = list()
    for i in range(5):
        l.append(bind(i))
    return l

for f in A():
    print( f() )
```

This way you can obtain the expected behaviour, since the binding is now on a value and not on a variable. Of course this is something tricky, and you should pay attemption to the behaviours of function like this, since python is using late binding.