# How to clean Python's environment

Tags: python

I have an app that creates Python code and runs it. During this process there are two method assignments that I'd like to clear as they create an error in the second run:

```
push = Writer.Push  
...  
def appPush(self):
    push(self)
    dumpRow(self)
...  
Writer.Push=appPush
```

It's a legacy code I have to fix. If you run this more than once, Python announces that there's a recursion.
I've been looking for a way to clear the environment but 'os.system('CLS')' didn't help. How can I clean those assignments?
Thanks.

Edit:
It IS legacy code. I'm not very familiar with it yet. My app creates Python code that contains general stuff (like the bit I've posted above) and a translation of the user's workflow to Python. If the user creates a flow that ends up calling 'appPush', the application has to be restarted after 1 run.
I can add stuff after the above code. What I'm looking for is a way to clear the interpreter's environment from those assignment. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to clear the console?

Comment: I don't want a clear screen (no need for many \n). I want those assignments undone somehow.

Comment: I need to see more code to understand your problem. `os.system('cls')` is *not* what you want there.

Comment: This is the problem. Those 2 assignments cause a recursion together when code containing them runs more than once. 'appPush' is calling itself recursively.

Comment: If it's written the way you currently have it, where everything is in the same method or whatever, it shouldn't call itself recursively because it would be a different `appPush` every time. It might call `dumpRow` more times then you want, though. So I'm asking for more context to see how you're getting recursion here.

Comment: Can't you change the creation of these assignments directly in the "app that creates python code" ? If not, I guess it's because it's legacy, right ? Where exactly do you want to control the situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I see what your problem is.

This code:

```
push = Writer.Push  
def appPush(self):
    push(self)
    dumpRow(self)
Writer.Push=appPush
```

Would cause infinite recursion if `push` were ever changed to `appPush`. What you basically want there is a decorator, so if you could change that to:

```
def appPushCreator(func):
    def appPush(self):
        func(self)
        dumpRow(self)
    return appPush

Writer.Push = appPushCreator(Writer.Push)
```

This would keep the implied semantics of doing another `dumpRow` every time you used that bit of code.

I don't think you can fix your error by only adding code *after* the broken bit. You can't 'clear the environment' and get your original `Writer.Push` back.

Comment: This seems to be just the thing I needed, Thanks! Now I'd like to dig in some documentation so I can understand it completely. Any recommendations?

Comment: @Noich: This actually runs into some subtlety with Python's lexical closure definition. It's the sort of fun you encounter when you use functional programming but don't disallow side-effects. It's discussed in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/lexical-closures-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
real_push = None
if real_push is None:
    real_push = push
Writer.Push = real_push
```

It might work better to put in code before the broken code:

```
real_push = None
if real_push is None:
    real_push = Writer.Push
Writer.Push = real_push
```

Essentially you're trying to make the code *idempotent* i.e. running it more than once has the same effect as running it once.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just test `Writer.Push is appPush` in Python 2.x because `Writer.Push` gets wrapped in an unbound method, but you can access attributes on `Writer.Push` and they go through to the original function. Also, if you use an attribute that means it doesn't matter if you don't have the original patch function around to test against. That means this should work:

```
def appPush(self):
    push(self)
    dumpRow(self)
appPush.is_patch = True
...

if not hasattr(Writer.Push, 'is_patch'):
    push = Writer.Push
    Writer.Push=appPush
```

Note that you want to move the assignment to `push` inside the `if` to avoid overwriting it when the code runs for a second time.