# Python import all functions from files within a directory into one namespace

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an `__init__.py` file which will import all functions from *.py files from a directory into a namespace (the directory's name). The logic is shown below:

```
for f in os.listdir(wd):
    if not f.endswith('.py') or f == '__init__.py':
        continue
    names = get_public_functions(open(wd + f))
    try:
        mod = __import__(f[:-3], fromlist=names)
        for fn in names:
            fun = getattr(mod, fn)
            setattr(sys.modules[__name__], fn, fun)
    except Exception as e: 
        for fn in names:
            setattr(sys.modules[__name__], fn, lambda: str(e))
```

So, you can observe that if there are syntax error in a file, the functions will still be imported, but they will return the syntax error (as a string).

What's frustrating, is that when there are syntax errors in multiple files, while I'm expecting something like:

```
mymodule.fn() => error1,
mymodule.fn2() => error1 (these were from the first file),
mymodule.fn3() => error2 etc.
```

I get only the last error message. I think the error must be in the `except` block, but I can't figure it. Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local variables in Python nested functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the value of `e` to the scope of the lambda you create. Or rather, you want to bind the `str(e)` result to the lambda:

```
error = str(e)
for fn in names:
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], fn, lambda error=error: error
```

Now each lambda has a keyword parameter storing the then-current value of `error`. Because the `error` parameter is a keyword parameter with a default value, your lambdas still work when called with arguments.

The alternative would be to create a new function scope:

```
def errorfunction(error):
    return lambda: error

error = str(e)
for fn in names:
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], fn, errorfunction(error)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the functions without arguments?

Comment: @gg.kaspersky: Not without creating another nested scope. Your function can be called without an argument (it has a default value).

Comment: Yes, the default argument solve it. So, was the error because of for? I recall reading something about this...

Comment: @gg.kaspersky: The outer loop can assign another exception to `e`, and you don't call your lambdas until the loop is already done. The lambdas all refer to the same `e` variable (a cell reference), so they all, in the end, point to the same exception, the last one raised in the loops.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky: I've marked your question a dupe where I explained this in more detail; I couldn't find that one at first.