# Local scope, beyond the scope of the enclosing

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

Why lambda function to get the list of values ​​i = 4 .During the call lambda, enclosing scope does not exist. The function f has finished work and returned control (the variable i does not exist).

```
def f():
    L = []
    for i in range(5): 
        L.append(lambda x: i ** x) 
    return L
L = f()
L[0]



def f1(N):
    def f2(X):
        return X**N
    return f2
f=f1(2) 
f (3)  
 9
g = f1(3)
g(3)
27
f(3)
9
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python uses [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) to capture references to the original variable. The `lambda` objects retain a reference to the `i` name, through which the value can be accessed. This means that the `i` variable continues to live on after `f` completes.

You can introspect this closure in the `.__closure__` tuple on the lambda objects; functions have the same attribute:

```
>>> L[0].__closure__
(<cell at 0x1077f8b78: int object at 0x107465880>,)
>>> L[0].__closure__[0]
<cell at 0x1077f8b78: int object at 0x107465880>
>>> L[0].__closure__[0].cell_contents
4
```

This is also why *all* lambdas in your list `L` refer to the value `4`, and not to the numbers 0 through to 4. They all refer to the *same* closure:

```
>>> L[0].__closure__[0] is L[1].__closure__[0]
True
```

The closure refers to the *variable*, not to the value of that variable at the time the closure was defined. At the end of the loop `i` was last set to `4`, so when looking up `i` in the lambda closure `4` will be found, for all lambdas in your list.

If you want your lambdas to refer to the value of `i` during the loop, capture it in a keyword argument:

```
def f():
    L = []
    for i in range(5): 
        L.append(lambda x, i=i: i ** x) 
    return L
```

Now `i` is a local variable to the lambda, not a closure.

Alternatively, create an entirely new scope from which to draw the closure:

```
def create_lambda(i):
    return lambda x: i ** x

def f():
    return [create_lambda(i) for i in range(5)]
```

Now `create_lambda()` is a new scope with it's own local `i` for the lambda closure to refer to. The lambdas then each have their own closures:

```
>>> L[0].__closure__[0] is L[1].__closure__[0]
False
```

Closures refer to a variable in a specific namespace; each time you call a function a new local namespace is created, so each closure refers to `i` in `create_lambda` in a separate namespace from other calls to `create_lambda`.

Comment: @user2494676: anything else you wanted to know? Any specific reason you are accepting then unaccepting my answer once in a while?

Comment: If lambda closed, why do not they have different values ​​in each iteration? i = 4 only in the final iteration

Comment: @user2494676: They all refer to the *variable*. `i` is assigned `4` last. By the time the function is done, `i` is still and will remain `4`.

Comment: @user2494676: see [Local variables in Python nested functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12423750)

Comment: three functions created when i is not yet equal to four.
i = 4, only when a last function.   For example

Comment: Yes, but `i` is looked up *when you execute the function*. The closure doesn't refer to the value, it refers to the variable. When you call the lambda, `i` is 4. It may have been 0, 1, 2 or 3 before when you defined the lambda, *but it is no longer now*.

Comment: Ok, 
Why is this code function f is not looking for a new variable N?

Comment: @user2494676: The closure is tied to a variable for a *given namespace*. Each time you run `f1()` a new namespace is created.