# Python - How to make tkinter Entry boxes disappear after choice change

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run my Python GUI script it will give you a drop down box to choose a website. The drop down box reads from a list called "sites".
When I choose "Fareham" buttons come up giving me a choice of "Custom Date", "Last Week", "Week to Current" if I press custom date 2 entry boxes come up, if I change my choice by pressing "week to current" 1 entry box is meant to come up.

When I press "week to current" just after pressing "custom date" the 2 entry boxes "custom date" creates don't disappear. How can I make the entry boxes disappear if my choice changes?

Code:

```
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

sites = [
    "Fareham",
    "Hants",
    "Southampton",
    "Eastleigh",
    "Havant",
    "Gosport",
]

win = tkinter.Tk()

win.geometry("500x500")

win.title("UK Council Web Scraping GUI | Sites Loaded: %s" % len(sites))

tkinter.Label(win, text="Database Path").grid(row=0, sticky="W")

entry1 = tkinter.Entry(win)
entry1.insert(0, "")
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W")

tkinter.Label(win, text="Log File Path").grid(row=1, sticky="W")

entry2 = tkinter.Entry(win)
entry2.insert(0, "")
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")

tkinter.Label(win, text="Chrome Driver Path").grid(row=2, sticky="W")

entry3 = tkinter.Entry(win)
entry3.insert(0, "")
entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W")

variable = tkinter.StringVar(win)
variable.set("Select Website")

homepath = "%homepath%"
choice = 0

def check(*args):
    global choice
    def custom():
        global choice
        choice = 1
        tkinter.Label(win, text="Start Date").grid(row=15, column=0)
        entry4 = tkinter.Entry(win)
        entry4.insert(0, "")
        entry4.grid(row=16, column=0)
        tkinter.Label(win, text="Stop Date").grid(row=15, column=1)
        entry5 = tkinter.Entry(win)
        entry5.insert(0, "")
        entry5.grid(row=16, column=1)

    def week():
        global choice
        choice = 2

    def wtc():
        global choice
        choice = 3
        tkinter.Label(win, text="Weeks").grid(row=15, column=0)
        entry4 = tkinter.Entry(win)
        entry4.insert(0, "")
        entry4.grid(row=16, column=0)

    if args[0] == "Fareham" or args[0] == "Southampton" or args[0] == "Eastleigh" or args[0] == "Havant" or args[0] == "Gosport":
        button1 = tkinter.Button(win, text="Custom Date", height=2, width=12, command=custom).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")
        button2 = tkinter.Button(win, text="Last Week", height=2, width=12, command=week).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="W")
        button3 = tkinter.Button(win, text="Week to Current", height=2, width=12, command=wtc).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="W")
    else:
        choice = 0

drop = tkinter.OptionMenu(win, variable, *sites, command=check).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="E")

def scrape(*args):
    global choice
    if choice == 0:
        os.system(r"cd %s\Anaconda3 && python %s\Desktop\code\urls\%s.py %s %s %s" % (homepath, homepath, variable.get().lower(), entry1.get(), entry2.get(), entry3.get()))

    if choice == 1:
        os.system(r"cd %s\Anaconda3 && python %s\Desktop\code\urls\%s.py %s %s %s 1 %s %s" % (homepath, homepath, variable.get().lower(), entry1.get(), entry2.get(), entry3.get(), entry4.get(), entry5.get()))

    if choice == 2:
        os.system(r"cd %s\Anaconda3 && python %s\Desktop\code\urls\%s.py %s %s %s 2" % (homepath, homepath, variable.get().lower(), entry1.get(), entry2.get(), entry3.get()))

    if choice == 3:
        os.system(r"cd %s\Anaconda3 && python %s\Desktop\code\urls\%s.py %s %s %s 3 %s" % (homepath, homepath, variable.get().lower(), entry1.get(), entry2.get(), entry3.get(), entry4.get()))

button4 = tkinter.Button(win, text="Scrape Website", height=2, width=12, command=scrape).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="W")

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read about [destroying-a-dynamically-created-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512297/destroying-a-dynamically-created-widget)

Answer (score 1):

The `Entry` widgets don't disappear because you haven't told them to.

You need to give a command to remove the widgets in order to make them go away.

Widgets are destroyed with the `.destroy()` function. To do this, you will need a way to refer to the two widgets `entry4` and `entry5` outside of the function where they are declared. There are two *easy* methods to achieve this.

The first (and one I would recommend) is to move to an OOP style in your program. Bryan's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/4528269) is a good starting point for achieving this.

The second is to make the variables global, this would involve adding the below snippet in the `custom()` function:

```
global entry4
global entry5
```

Either way, you will then be able to refer to the widgets outside of the function and can then call `.destroy()` on them like below:

---

Method 1:

```
CLASS_NAME.entry4.destroy()
CLASS_NAME.entry5.destroy()
```

Method 2:

```
global entry4
global entry5
entry4.destroy()
entry5.destroy()
```

---

Note, however, that this does not destroy the labels you have also created. As these are anonymous widgets they will be harder to remove. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804796/4528269) for some information.