# Add methods to a class generated from other methods

Tags: python

I have classes like this:

```
class Tool(object):
    def do_async(*args):
        pass
```

for which I want to automatically generate non-async methods that make use of the async methods:

```
class Tool(object):
    def do_async(*args):
        pass
    def do(*args):
        result = self.do_async(*args)
        return magical_parser(result)
```

This gets to be particularly tricky because each method needs to be accessible as *both* an object and class method, which is normally achieved with this magical decorator:

```
class class_or_instance(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is not None:
            f = lambda *args, **kwds: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwds)
        else:
            f = lambda *args, **kwds: self.fn(cls, *args, **kwds)
        functools.update_wrapper(f, self.fn)
        return f
```

How can I make these methods, and make sure they're accessible as both class and object methods?  This seems like something that could be done with decorators, but I am not sure how.

(Note that I don't know any of the method names in advance, but I know that all of the methods that need new buddies have `_async` at the end of their names.)

I think I've gotten fairly close, but this approach does not appropriately set the functions as class/object methods:

```
def process_asyncs(cls):

    methods = cls.__dict__.keys()
    for k in methods:
        methodname = k.replace("_async","")
        if 'async' in k and methodname not in methods:

            @class_or_instance
            def method(self, verbose=False, *args, **kwargs):
                response = self.__dict__[k](*args,**kwargs)
                result = self._parse_result(response, verbose=verbose)
                return result

            method.__docstr__ = ("Returns a table object.\n" +
                    cls.__dict__[k].__docstr__)

            setattr(cls,methodname,MethodType(method, None, cls))
```

Comment: What are the semantics for calling these methods as instance or class methods? Do they even use the instance for anything when called as instance methods? This sounds like a job for module-level functions, or perhaps `staticmethod` if you're really, absolutely sure these things need to be methods.

Comment: Yes, normally these would just be module-level functions, but there are some cases in which an instance is needed.  Basically, this is for a suite of web querying tools, where normally you can just use the classmethod, but sometimes you need to use the object to log in to the service first.  There may be better ways, but this approach has worked well so far.  (work in progress: astroquery.readthedocs.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not get the other method from the `__dict__`; use `getattr()` instead so the descriptor protocol can kick in.

And don't wrap the `method` function in a `MethodType()` object as that'd neutralize the descriptor you put on `method`.

You need to *bind* `k` to the function you generate; a closured `k` would change with the loop:

```
@class_or_instance
def method(self, verbose=False, _async_method_name=k, *args, **kwargs):
    response = getattr(self, _async_method_name)(*args,**kwargs)
    result = self._parse_result(response, verbose=verbose)
    return result

cls.__dict__[methodname] = method
```

Don't forget to return `cls` at the end; I've changed this to use a separate function to create a new scope to provide a new local name `_async_method_name` instead of a keyword parameter; this avoids difficulties with `*args` and explicit keyword arguments:

```
def process_asyncs(cls):

    def create_method(async_method):

        @class_or_instance
        def newmethod(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if 'verbose' in kwargs:
                verbose = kwargs.pop('verbose')
            else:
                verbose = False
            response = async_method(*args,**kwargs)
            result = self._parse_result(response, verbose=verbose)
            return result
        return newmethod

    methods = cls.__dict__.keys()
    for k in methods:
        methodname = k.replace("_async","")
        if 'async' in k and methodname not in methods:
            async_method = getattr(cls, k)
            setattr(cls, methodname, create_method(async_method))

    return cls
```

Comment: I had tried that, but got the error: `TypeError: 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment`.  My classes have `__metaclass__=abc.ABCMeta`; I don't really know if that's warranted or related to this.

Comment: Excellent.  I don't need to return `cls`, though, since it is modifying the class directly.  I've added the full version of this solution to the answer above.

Comment: If you are using it as a decorator, you *do* need to return `cls` because python replaces the decorated object with whatever the decorator returns.

Comment: Good point!  That's a much nicer way to do this.  I'm still having trouble with the docstrings, but the decorator works as it should (once `return cls` is added).  Awesome!

Comment: Your posted solution in your question will suffer from the fact `async_method` is a closure in a loop; all your generated methods will point to **one** async method.

Comment: See [Local variables in Python nested functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614) for a more thorough explanation of what will go wrong with the `async_method` name in your code, and why I bound `k` to a keyword argument in my solution.

Comment: You're quite right, and thanks for pointing to that other article.  This is somewhat surprising behavior (probably because I haven't fully internalized the problem) and I doubt I would have figured it out without the explicit note.

Comment: Unfortunately, specifying the arguments in this manner means that it is impossible to pass positional arguments to `newmethod`, which is actually required.  Is there any workaround?  (`def newmethod(self, *args, _async_method=async_method, **kwargs):` is not allowed)

Comment: Yes, by creating a new scope; use a *separate* function that returns `newmethod()` when called. See the linked question from my previous comment.

Comment: Updated to do just that.

Comment: There is one more major issue that I've resolved: if you use `getattr` to get the method, it only gets the *class* method, it will never return an instance's attribute.  To get around this, bind the *name* instead of the method.  See https://github.com/keflavich/astroquery/blob/30deafc3aa057916bcdca70733cba748f1b36b64/astroquery/utils/process_asyncs.py for the full solution.

Comment: Yup, which is what my original answer did but your edit cached the method instead. :-) A late lookup allows you to find instance attributes too, yes.