# Function name is not reusable (python)

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to create functions and add them to a list, reusing the same name every time.

```
def fconstruct():
    flist  = []
    for x in xrange(0,5):
        def kol():
            return x
        flist.append(kol)
        del kol #this doesn't fix the problem.
    return flist

k = fconstruct()
```

However, this fails, even if i delete the function every loop, and no matter which of the functions in k i call, the result is the the same: 4, because the newest definition of kol has changed all the previous ones. For a simple function such as this,

```
kol = lambda: x
```

would work. However, i need to do this for a much more complex function

As solutions, i could store the function as a string in the list and use exec to call it.

I could generate disposable and random function names:

```
fname = '_'+str(random.random())
exec fname + ' = kol'
exec 'flist.append('+fname+')'
```

I could play around with this implementation of multiline lambdas: https://github.com/whaatt/Mu

None of these seem elegant, so what is the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I want to use scipy.optimize.leastsq which asks for a function that returns multiple values (presumably one from each equation). I'm putting the functions into a list so i can call them and return the values separately. Now that you mention it, I guess I could just store the values rather than all the separate functions. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local variables in Python nested functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions)

Comment: This has nothing to do with function names and everything with closures..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're defining `kol`, you're establishing a closure around `x`. In fact, each time through the loop you're getting a closure around the same variable.

So while you have 5 different functions all named `kol`, they all return the value of the same variable. When the loop is finished, that variable's value is 4, so each function returns 4.

Consider this:

```
def fconstruct():
    flist = []
    for x in range(5):
        def get_kol(y):
            def kol():
                return y
            return kol
        flist.append(get_kol(x))

    return flist
```

In this case, the function `get_kol()` returns a function who's return value is `get_kol()`'s argument.

The closure in `kol()` is now around `y`, which is local to the `get_kol()` function, not the loop. Each time `get_kol()` is called, a new local `y` is created, so each `kol()` gets a different variable closure.

---

An alternative way is to create a partial function with [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial). This accomplishes the same thing (creates a function which, when called executes another function with arguments), and is a lot more powerful

```
def f(a): # whatever arguments you like
    return a

# create a bunch of functions that return f(x)
flist = [functools.partial(f, x) for x in range(5)]

def g(a, b): 
    return a + b

# create a bunch of functions that take a single argument (b), but have a set to
# 0..4: 
flist = [functools.partial(g, x) for x in range(5)] 

some_g = flist[0]
some_g(1) # returns 0 + 1
```

Comment: I would put `get_kol` outside the loop, because it is not necessary to create a new factory on every iteration.

Comment: I'm glad you guys stepped up, I didn't have time to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use another function that generates the function you want with the x parameter set. Here I use the `kol_factory` (see also the answer to [Closures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020443/2297345)):

```
def fconstruct():
    flist  = []
    # create a function g with the closure x
    def kol_factory(y):
        # y is local here
        def kol():
            # kol uses the y
            return y
        return kol
    for x in xrange(0,5):
        # we create a new g with x "burned-in"
        flist.append(kol_factory(x))
    return flist

for k in  fconstruct():
   print k()
```

You can define the factory function factory outside the `fconstruct` function:

```
def kol_factory(y):
    # y is local here
    def kol():
        # kol uses the y
        return y
    return kol

def fconstruct():
    flist  = []
    for x in xrange(0,5):
        # we create a new kol_factory with x "burned-in"
        flist.append(kol_factory(x))
    return flist

for k in  fconstruct():
   print k()
```