# Function factory using nested functions and factory class in Python

Tags: python, factory, nested-function

I went through examples of function factories, but I still cannot understand something... I have a class `Sample`. For objects instantiated from that class, I have an attribute: a function `f` telling me different words (e.g. 'one' or 'two'). To do so, I create a `Factory`, where I define `f` for each sample. All samples are stored in `SampleCollection` class. Then, I call function f for each sample from the collection. I cannot understand why the output 'two' and 'two', and not 'one' and 'two' as I would expect...

```
class Sample():

    def __init__(self):
        self.f = None

    def call_f(self):
        print self.f()

class SampleCollection():

    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []

    def add(self, sample):
        self.container.append(sample)

class Factory():

    def __init__(self, collection):
        self.collection = collection

    def generate_f(self, words):

        for w in words:
            def f(): return w

            s = Sample()
            s.f = f
            self.collection.add(s)

col = SampleCollection()
fab = Factory(col)

words = ['one', 'two']
fab.generate_f(words)

for s in col.container:
    s.call_f()
```

**UPD:** Thank you for your answers! I didn't know how it is called correctly. Example solution is to change the function definition: `def f(w=w): return w`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614/3001761

Comment: also http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures