# Making list of function using list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda

I want to make a list of functions using a list comprehension. What I have is the following:

```
f = [lambda x:x*i for i in range(3)]
```

As far as I understand `f` is a list of functions.

Now if I call the first function via:

```
f[0](100)
```

I get 300 and also calling the second function `f[1](100)` I get 300. I don't understand why I don't get 0 in the first call and 100 after my second call.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614/3001761

Comment: And this [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/3di1ttzAuwY).

Comment: I wonder how you can get 300. I get 200.