# Use cls.__dict__ to generate method with lambda

Tags: python, class, lambda, class-method

I wrote these classes to define a HTTP response:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

class BaseResponse:
    code = {
        'SUCCESS': [0, ''],
        'FAIL':[-1, '']
    }

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def response(cls, error, code, ret):
        ret = {
            'error':error,
            'code':code,
            'ret':ret
        }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ret))

    @classmethod
    def responseWithCodeName(cls, codeName, ret):
        print "%s\t%s" % (codeName, ret)
        # return cls.response(cls.code[codeName][1], cls.code[codeName][0], ret)

    @classmethod
    def addCoding(cls, codename, code, msg):
        cls.code[codename]=[code, msg]

    @classmethod
    def inherCode(cls):
        cls.code.update(BaseResponse.code)

    @classmethod
    def generateResponseProperties(cls):
        for item in cls.code.keys():
            print item
            print cls.code[item]
            cls.__dict__[item] = staticmethod(
                lambda ret : cls.responseWithCodeName(item, ret)
            )


class BannerResponse(BaseResponse):
    code = dict()

class AuthResponse(BaseResponse):
    code = dict()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    BannerResponse.inherCode()
    BannerResponse.addCoding('NOBANNER', '1', "no banner got")
    BannerResponse.generateResponseProperties()
    BannerResponse.NOBANNER('nobanner')
    BannerResponse.SUCCESS('success')
    BannerResponse.FAIL('fail')
```

The results of running this code are:

```
FAIL
[-1, '']
NOBANNER
['1', 'no banner got']
SUCCESS
[0, '']
SUCCESS nobanner // This should be 'NOBANNER nobanner'
SUCCESS success 
SUCCESS fail // This should be "FAIL fail"
```

Note that the output of `generateResponseProperties()` is correct! Is there any secret of python when I use class in this way?

Sorry that the answer in [local-variables-in-python-nested-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions) do not help me. I have tried the solution in that question, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: You'd do better to use `setattr(cls, item, ...)`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Eric: the question is why the `generateResponseProperties ` class method appears to only use `item = 'SUCCESS'` in the loop. See the duplicate.

Comment: @Eric The results are wrong

Comment: I known how to solve this problem