# How to generate a list of different lambda functions with list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, list-comprehension

This question is distilled from the original application involving callback functions for Tkinter buttons.  This is one line that illustrates the behavior.

`lambdas = [lambda: i for i in range(3)]`

if you then try invoking the lambda functions generated:
`lambdas[0]()`, `lambdas[1]()` and `lambdas[2]()` all return 2.

The desired behavior was to have `lambdas[0]()` return 0, `lambdas[1]()` return 1, `lambdas[2])()` return 2.

I see that the index variable is interpreted by reference.  The question is how to rephrase to have it treated by value.

Comment: `[lambda i = i: i for i in range(3)]`

Comment: Canonical duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614/3001761. *"the index variable is interpreted by reference"* - no, it's a late-binding thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create specialized functions from a more general one by partial application, which reduces the parameter count by one:

```
from functools import partial
lambdas = [partial(lambda x: x, i) for i in range(3)]
```

Here, `lambda x: x` is the general identity function taking one argument, and you create three specializations of it, taking no arguments, and returning fixed values.

Answer (score 6):

Use a parameter with default value to bind the *current value* of `i` to a local variable. When the `lambda` gets called without an argument, the local variable `i` is assigned the default value:

```
In [110]: lambdas = [lambda i=i: i for i in range(3)]

In [111]: for lam in lambdas:
   .....:       print(lam())
   .....: 
0
1
2
```

When `i` is not a local variable, Python [looks up its value in the enclosing scope](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). The value that is found is the last value `i` attained in the for-loop of the list comprehension. That is why, without the parameter with default value, each `lambda` returns 2 since the for-loop has completed by the time the lambdas get called.

---

Another common approach to solving this problem is to use a closure -- [a function that can refer to environments that are no longer active](http://effbot.org/zone/closure.htm) *such as the local namespace of an outer function, even after that function has returned*.

```
def make_func(i):
    return lambda: i

lambdas = [make_func(i) for i in range(3)]
for lam in lambdas:
    print(lam())
```

prints

```
0
1
2
```

This works because when `lam()` gets called, since the `i` in the `lambda`
function's body is not a local variable, Python looks for the value of `i` in
the enclosing scope of the function `make_func`. Its local namespace is still
accessible to the closure, `lam`, even though `make_func` has already
completed. The value in that local namespace is the value which was passed to
`make_func`, which is, happily, the desired value of `i`.

---

As [already mentioned by mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31187259/190597),
another way to create a new function with some argument values already supplied
is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
lambdas = [functools.partial(lambda x: x, i) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Demonstrate a partial function too. +1 for using a function def. Although I would avoid lambdas altogether.

Answer (score 4):

The important thing to be understood here is, **the functions are created during the evaluation of the list comprehension, but the value of `i` will be evaluated only during the execution of the functions.**

So, in your case, you have created three functions and all of them refer `i`. When those functions are invoked at runtime, `i` will have the value `2`, because that was the last value bound to `i` in the last iteration of the `for` loop.

---

Instead, you need to preserve the current value of `i` in each of the functions created. So, the common practice is to include a default parameter, like this

```
>>> lambdas = [lambda i=i: i for i in range(3)]
>>> lambdas[0]()
0
>>> lambdas[1]()
1
>>> lambdas[2]()
2
```

Now, `lambda i=i: i`, creates a default parameter `i` which will have the current value of the loop variable `i`. So, when the functions are executed, the `i` referred is actually the parameter passed to the function, not the loop variable.

To avoid confusion, you can choose to use a different name for the variable, like this

```
>>> lambdas = [lambda t=i: t for i in range(3)]
```

---

If you are looking other ways to avoid this, you can use `map` function to apply the numbers to another function which will generate new functions with the current value, like this

```
>>> lambdas = map(lambda x: lambda: x, range(3))
>>> lambdas[0]()
0
>>> lambdas[1]()
1
>>> lambdas[2]()
2
```

Here, `lambda x: lambda: x` creates an anonymous function which accepts a single parameter `x`, and returns another function which doesn't accept any parameters but returns the value `x`.

**Note:** Don't use this `map` form in actual code. It might reduce the readability of the code.

Comment: @Kasra True, that would reduce the confusion. Thanks for the suggestion, I included it in the answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye Your answer is a bit confusing, why using `map` in one case and `[... for i in ...]` in the other? Why not `map(lambda v: lambda x=v: x, range(3))` or `[(lambda v: lambda: v) (i) for i in range(3)]`? The way I read your answer is that the second solution is the use of `map` while actually it is the use of a `lambda v: lambda: v`.

Comment: @thefourtheye I understood your answer, I am just saying that the way your answer is written, it looks like you are saying that the important part of the second solution is the `map` while in fact it is the `lambda x: lambda: x`. I would have used `[... for i in ...]` or `map` in both case to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: @Holt I see what you are saying now. I updated the text a bit now. Please check.

Answer (score -2):

Ahhh, further Googling found a solution (admittedly one I would not have stumbled upon myself). The desired behavior can be invoked by use of a default argument:

`lambdas = [lambda i=i: i for i in range(3)]`