# Generate references to closures

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to generate a list of slightly different functions to be dynamically constructed:

```
def f(p,x):
    print("f", p, x)

a=[]
for param in ('param_A', 'param_B'):
    a.append( lambda x: f(param, x) )
```

Result:

```
IN:    a[0](0)
OUT:   f param_B 0
IN:    a[1](1)
OUT:   f param_B 1
```

While I will probably solve the problem by using functors instead, would be interesting to know the mechanics of variable binding and what is the simple fix for the above example

Comment: *"what is the simple fix?"*: `lambda x, param=param: ...`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614/3001761

Comment: @NightShadeQueen that's *inside* the lambda, so won't work, and puts a positional argument after a keyword one.