# What's the logic behind this particular Python functions composition?

Tags: python, function, composition

Consider the following Python snippet concerning functions composition:

```
from functools import reduce
def compose(*funcs):
    # compose a group of functions into a single composite (f(g(h(..(x)..)))
    return reduce(lambda f, g: lambda *args, **kwargs: f(g(*args, **kwargs)), funcs)


### --- usage example:
from math import sin, cos, sqrt
mycompositefunc = compose(sin,cos,sqrt)
mycompositefunc(2)
```

I have two questions:

1. Can someone please explain me the `compose` "operational logic"? (How it works?)
2. Would it be possible (and how?) to obtain the same thing [without using reduce](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) for this?

I already looked [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), [here](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php) and [here too](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php), my problem is *NOT* understanding what `lambda` means or `reduce` does (I think I got, for instance, that `2` in the usage example will be somewhat the first element in `funcs` to be composed).
What I find harder to understand is rather the complexity of how the two `lambda`s got combined/nested and mixed with `*args, **kwargs` here as `reduce` first argument ...

---

**EDIT:**

First of all, @Martijn and @Borealid, thank you for your effort and answers and for the time you are dedicating to me. (Sorry for the delay, I do this in my spare time and not always have a a lot...)

Ok, coming to facts now...

***About 1st point on my question:***

Before anything, I realized what I didn't really got (but I hope I did now) about those `*args, **kwargs` variadic arguments before is that *at least* `**kwargs` **is not mandatory** (I say well, right?)
This made me understand, for instance, why `mycompositefunc(2)` works with that only one (non keyword) passed argument.

I realized, then, that the example would work even replacing those `*args, **args` in the inner lambda with a simple `x`. I imagine that's because, in the example, all 3 composed functions (`sin, cos, sqrt`) expect one (and one only) parameter... and, of course, return a single result... so, more specifically, it works because the **first** composed function expect just one parameter (the following others will *naturally* get only one argument here, that's the result of the previous composed functions, so you COULDN'T compose functions that expect more than one argument after the first one... I know it's a bit contort but I think you got what I'm trying to explain...)

**Now coming to what remains the real unclear matter for me here:**

```
lambda f, g: lambda *args, **kwargs: f(g(*args, **kwargs))
```

**How does that lambda nesting "magic" works?**

With all the great respect you deserve and I bear you,
 it seems to me like both of you are wrong coming to the conclusion the final result shall be: `sqrt(sin(cos(*args, **kw)))`.
It actually can't be, the order of appliance of the sqrt function is clearly reversed: it's not the last to be composed but the first.

I say this because:

```
>>> mycompositefunc(2)
0.1553124117201235
```

its result is equal to

```
>>> sin(cos(sqrt(2)))
0.1553124117201235
```

whereas you get an error with

```
>>> sqrt(sin(cos(2)))
[...]
ValueError: math domain error
```

(that's due to trying to squareroot a negative float)

```
#P.S. for completeness:

>>> sqrt(cos(sin(2)))
0.7837731062727799

>>> cos(sin(sqrt(2)))
0.5505562169613818
```

So, I understand that the functions composition will be made from the last one to the first ( i.e. : compose(sin,cos,sqrt) => sin(cos(sqrt(x))) ) but the "*why?*" and **how does that lambda nesting "magic" works?** still remains a bit unclear for me... Help/Suggestions very appreciated!

***On 2nd point (about rewriting compose without reduce)***

@Martijn Pieters:
your first compose (the "wrapped" one) works and returns exactly the same result

```
>>> mp_compfunc = mp_compose(sin,cos,sqrt)
>>> mp_compfunc(2)
0.1553124117201235
```

The unwrapped version, instead, unfortunately loops until `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` ...

@Borealid: your foo/bar example will not get more than two functions for composition but I think it was just for explanations not intended for answering to second point, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*args, **kw` syntax in both the `lambda` signature and call syntax are the best way to pass on *arbitrary arguments*. They accept any number of positional and keyword arguments and just pass those on to a next call. You could write the result of the outer `lambda` as:

```
def _anonymous_function_(*args, **kw):
    result_of_g = g(*args, **kw)
    return f(result_of_g)
return _anonymous_function
```

The `compose` function can be rewritten without `reduce()` like this:

```
def compose(*funcs):
    wrap = lambda f, g: lambda *args, **kw: f(g(*args, **kw))
    result = funcs[0]
    for func in funcs[1:]:
        result = wrap(result, func)
    return result
```

This does the exact same thing as the `reduce()` call; call the lambda for the chain of functions.

So, the first two functions in the sequence are `sin` and `cos`, and these are replaced by:

```
lambda *args, **kw: sin(cos(*args, **kw))
```

This then is passed to the *next* call as `f`, with `sqrt` `g`, so you get:

```
lambda *args, **kw: (lambda *args, **kw: sin(cos(*args, **kw)))(sqrt(*args, **kw)))
```

which can be simplified to:

```
lambda *args, **kw: sin(cos(sqrt(*args, **kw)))
```

because `f()` is a lambda that passes its arguments to the nested `sin(cos())` call.

In the end, then, you have produced a function that calls `sqrt()`, the result of which is passed to `cos()`, and the output of that is then passed to `sin()`. The `*args, **kw` lets you pass in any number of arguments or keyword arguments, so the `compose()` function can be applied to *anything* than is callable, provided that all but the first function takes just one argument, of course.

Comment: It would be better to use `lambda x: x` as an initial value for the `reduce`, or the loop in your answer: that way `compose()` is the correct composition of zero functions -- a function that does nothing.

Comment: @Mauris: but it would not reflect the result of the `reduce()` function as posted in the question.

Comment: @Mauris: Martijn is right on the fact it would not reflect the original  function as posted in the question, nice suggestion anyway +1 !

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Hey, wait... I think I heard of you before, you must be the legendary Python ninja, isn't it? :-)
Thank you for your reply and for the time you are dedicating to me.
I edited my question after your answer, could you please take a look again at it?

Comment: @danicotra: ack, you are correct, I read the lambda as producing `g(f(..))`, not `f(g(..))`. I remember a small niggle of a doubt that I apparently ignored while writing my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I just tried inverting those but it seems like the returned result will then be equal to `sqrt(cos(sin(2)))` ... did I miss something?

Comment: @danicotra: nope, you didn't. I've corrected my answer, by the way. The second version where I removed the wrapper is now gone; I had discounted for the effect of closures (see [Local variables in Python nested functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614), where I wrote an answer so I should have seen that coming), and to avoid the issue with you'd have to jump through some pretty major hoops that were not worth it here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: GREAT, thank you! I knew I had correctly guessed who you were! ;-D Accepted. ...If you didn't already, would you mind taking a look at [my other Python related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1078556+[python])? Thank you so much again!