# How can I pass a dict key to a decorator value within flask?

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to get my app.route decorator to accept a dictionary key as an argument instead of writing out each function separately.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

pages_dict = {"/url": "html_file.html", "/", "index.html"}


for k, v in pages_dict.items():

    @app.route(key)
    def render():
        return render_template(v)
```

Comment: The too-many-values is one you could easily have debugged yourself.. Then again, so was the typo in the dictionary.

Comment: But to cut a long story short: Stack Overflow is not an interactive debugger. Please stick to one issue per post, don't keep updating it with new issues as they arise.

Comment: Thanks for your help and yeah I'm sorry about that, I should of got those errors.

Answer (score 1):

You used a `,` comma where you should have used a `:` colon:

```
pages_dict = {"url": "html_file", "/", "index.html"}
                                     ^
```

This is easily corrected to:

```
pages_dict = {"url": "html_file", "/": "index.html"}
```

The `@app.route()` decorator registers *endpoints*, each of which have to have a unique name. By default the endpoint name is taken from the function, so if you are reusing a function you need to provide a name explicitly:

```
for k, v in pages_dict.items():
    @app.route(k, endpoint=k)
    def render():
        return render_template(v)
```

You'll still run into issues with closures here; the `v` used in `render()` is going to be bound to the *last value* from the loops. You probably want to pass it in as an argument to `render()` instead:

```
for k, v in pages_dict.items():
    @app.route(k, endpoint=k)
    def render(v=v):
        return render_template(v)
```

This binds `v` as a local in `render()` rather than leave it a closure. See [Local variables in Python nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions) for more details.

Comment: I've also tried this with iteritems but it still can't connect on localhost:5000 but I get no errors when I run the script, I'll keep trying, thanks for the help.

Comment: @EvanBlack: your example script has no `app.run()` call or a WSGI setup. Are you sure you started the builtin development server (`app.run()`) or have another WSGI setup?

Comment: I've messed about with it a bit but I can only get it to display one out of the two html pages, i'm going to try creating a function to create functions instead.

Comment: @EvanBlack: ah, yes, you'll run into issues with closures. Updated the answer to account for that.