# wxPython - button

Tags: python, wxpython

Here is my code:

```
for i in posortowane:
    z += 20
    result = '%s: %s' % (i[0], i[1])
    wx.StaticText(panel, -1, result, (345, 125 + z), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
    btn4 = wx.Button(panel, -1, u"Remove", (485, 120 + z))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Rem, btn4)
```

There are 2 buttons one below the other. They call Rem function:

```
def Rem(self, i):
    print i
```

I would like to write 'i' from 'posortowane' when I click button. It doesn't work. I tried:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Rem(i), btn4)
```

but it calls Rem function before I click a button. How can I achieve this? I am sorry for my english. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You are saying there are 2 buttons, but there is only one button created in the code. It would help the investigation if you could post more code.

Comment: I would like to add a button to every line in my program (it would be "name" and "delete" button next to it. I am trying to add settings to my program (using json). Program counts how many times in ms excell file "name" exists - name - 24, name1 - 46, name2 - 121 e.t.c. Names are strored in json file. I would like to add/remove names. I am not able to ask you what I want because of my poor english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add paranthesis, you are telling interpreter to call that function right away.
To pass parameters without calling callback immediatly, you should use [`lambda`](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks).

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, i: self.Rem(evt,i), btn4)
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I get "<wx._core.CommandEvent; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxCommandEvent *' at 0x5eef10> >" instead 'i'

Comment: I get "TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: @Luk `def Rem(self, evt, i): print i`

Comment: It works but it prints only last i. I have: name1 'btn', name2 'btn', name3 'btn', When I press btn next to name1 I get name3...

Comment: @Luk Please check these two about lambda and loop issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda && http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions

Comment: I tried this "command=lambda name=name: self.a(name))" but I get "<wx._core.CommandEvent; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxCommandEvent *' at 0x7ffea4ca4420> >"

Comment: @Luk `(..., lambda evt=evt , i=i: self.Rem(evt,i), ...)`