# Python: Pure functions constituting a list seem to be invalid syntax

Tags: python, list, plot, lambda

I am drawing dozens of functions as subplots, by storing pure functions as list. I find many different functions are considered the same. Here is a simplified example, where two cosine functions are drawn.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import math # cos
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt # Plotting.

scale =[0.01*x for x in list(range(200))]
list_fun =[lambda t: math.cos(2*math.pi*i*t) for i in [1,2]]

data_1 =list(map(list_fun[0], scale))
data_2 =list(map(list_fun[1], scale))

fig =plt.figure( figsize=(11,5) )

ax =fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1) # left
ax.plot( scale, data_1, label="cos 2$\pi$t" )
ax.legend()

ax =fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2) # right
ax.plot( scale, data_2, label="cos 4$\pi$t" )
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

The plot shows both `$\cos (4\pi t)$` functions, but one should be `$\cos (2\pi t)$`. I guess the list formed by several pure functions are invalid in python, is it so? If so, is there an alternative syntax? I am new to Python so there may have been some glaring errors.

Comment: Your `list_fun` lists contains two identical functions because of how you defined it. Both functions return `math.cos(2*math.pi*i*t)`, where `i` has its final value, 2

Comment: Use `lambda t, i=i: ... for i in [1,2]` to create a closure over the current value of `i`. Otherwise, `i` is simply a global (or nonlocal) variable in the body of the resulting function object, whose value is found when the function is called.

Comment: The old [late binding](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#id1) problem!

Comment: See [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) and https://sopython.com/canon/30/why-do-my-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions-created-in-a-loop-all-use-the-las/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions The code in that question uses a different technique to define the functions, but it's essentially the same problem. OTOH, at first glance, it's not clear that this question is a dupe of that one, so I'm not comfortable using it as a dupe target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `list_fun` list contains two identical functions because of how you defined it. Both functions return `math.cos(2*math.pi*i*t)`, where `i` has its final value, 2.

You could copy `i` to another variable to get this to work:

```
[lambda t, m=i: math.cos(2*math.pi*m*t) for i in [1,2]]
```

Comment: This is correct! But I am still struggling to understand the evaluation order....

Comment: @Aminopterin In khelwood's code the assignment of the default value `m=i` happens when the function is created, so `m` gets the desired value of `i` as its default value. In your code, the name `i` is looked up each time the function is called, and in this case `i` is found in the scope of the list comp where the function was created, where `i` has the value it was set to at the end of the `for` loop.