# Deep copy index integer using lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda, deep-copy

```
func = []

for value in range(5):
    func.append(lambda: print_index(value))


def print_index(index_to_print):
    print(index_to_print)


for a in func:
    a()
```

When I run the code above, the output is

```
4
4
4
4
4
```

Why is it not ?

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

What can I do to make it like the above.

I have tried importing copy and using `copy.deepcopy(index)`. I didn't work probably since index is an integer.

Is `lambda` part of the reason it is not working.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local variables in Python nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AChampion said, Python calculates the value of `value` when it needs to and not while executing the loop.

However for me it seemed easier to do the following fix.

```
func = []

for value in range(5):
    func.append(lambda v = value: print_index(v))


def print_index(index_to_print):
    print(index_to_print)


for a in func:
    a()
```

This is setting the default argument in the function which gets calculated during the loop execution. The code above is the same as saying :

```
func = []

for value in range(5):
    def anonymous_function(v=value):
        print_index(v)

    func.append(anonymous_function)


def print_index(index_to_print):
    print(index_to_print)


for a in func:
    a()
```

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but the reason that it is printing all `4`s is because Python uses dynamic name resolution of variables, that is the value of `value` when the functions are executed (not when it is declared) is used.

If you really need a function to print the value then you need to create a closure, which means creating the function inside another function, e.g.:

```
def make_closure(v):
    return lambda: print_index(v)

func = [] 
for value in range(5):
    func.append(make_closure(value))
```

Now this outputs:

```
In []:
for a in func:
    a()

Out[]:
0
1
2
3
4
```