# Lambda functions in python bypass object link

Tags: python, lambda

I understand how it's work, but how I can do that python print true and false in this case?)

```
def f(func, value):
        global a
        a = 2
        print(func(value))

a = 3
f(lambda x: x == a, 3)
f(lambda x: x == a, 2)
```

Comment: I understand what this code is doing, but not what your question is in regards to.  Maybe another example would help?

Comment: x == a take a as reference, but I need the value of a

Comment: The value of `a` changed because you declared it as a global and then changed it from inside your function.  What you were trying to accomplish instead?

Comment: I have a global value `a`, well, I need to remember the current value, so that if it suddenly changes `lambda` doesn’t change

Comment: Don't use a global value?  With normal scoping you get exactly that behavior.  It's only doing things you don't want because you declared it as a `global`, which is generally discouraged.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-nested-functions

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have the code check the value of `a` that you originally declared (i.e. 3) so that it prints `True`;`False` instead of the inverse, just don't set `a` to 2 inside your function:

```
def f(func, value):
        print(func(value))

a = 3
f(lambda x: x == a, 3)
f(lambda x: x == a, 2)
```

Using `global` is generally not recommended because it makes it very easy to confuse yourself by having values change in unexpected ways.