# What is the use of () in the Python code?

Tags: python

```
for x in range(10):
   arr.append(lambda:x**2)
arr[4]()
```

Expected output: 16 or nothing because no print statement
But output, when I run, is 81. Why so?

Comment: You're running this in an interactive interpreter. (That, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-nested-functions)

Comment: each element in an array is a function (or lambda). So arr[4] is a function and () is a function call

Comment: Also, it sounds like you already know what all the parentheses do in this code, if you understood enough to expect 16 or nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `arr.append(lambda:x**2)`, `x` is scoped outside the function.

When you finish the loop, `x` is set to 9 (0 to 9).

Then, `x**2` is 81, so `arr[4]()` will re-evaluate `x`, so the result is 81.

Just for fun, you can attempt what you want with the following:

```
f_generator = lambda i: lambda: i**2
arr = [f_generator(i) for i in range(10)]
arr[4]()  # 16
```

Comment: Actually  `arr[y]()` will return 81 for every `y`. Good answer, +1 OP

Comment: But when I call arr[4]() and arr[3]() it should return 81 and 81 but it only returns 81 once. Why so?

Comment: In your version, `arr[4]()` and `arr[3]()` are both returning 81.

Answer (score 0):

To get the effect you want, you should remove the lambda like this:

```
arr = []
for x in range(10):
   arr.append(x**2)
print(arr[4])
```

because otherwise you are storing a function, not a number. Notice that now you don't need `()`

Answer (score 0):

() is used for calling any object, it can be a method or class
like,

```
class Name:
    ...

Name()
```

or,

```
name = Name()
```