# Python: Append lambda functions to list

Tags: python, lambda, append

Can anyone do sanity check?

I'm trying to make functions in for-loop.
The point I can't understand is summarized in the following code:

```
f_list = []
for i in range(10):
    f = lambda j : i
    f_list.append(f)
```

Then,

```
>>> f_list[0](0)
9                  #I hope this is 0.
>>> f_list[1](0)
9                  #I hope this is 1.
```

Why is this happen??

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the past question/answers. Yes, this is actually a duplicate of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:** Almost the same problem is already discussed in Stackoverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/233673/1903116).

This is because of the closure property of python. To get what you actually need, you need to do like this

```
f = lambda j, i = i : i
```

So, the output of this program becomes like this

```
f_list = []
for i in range(5):
    f = lambda j, i = i : i
    f_list.append(f)

for i in range(5):    
    print f_list[i](0)
```

**Output**

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer. I understand the point.