# Is it possible to create a nested function with state in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a callback that updates if it's been more than a second since the last report.  It looks something like this

```
def main_func()
    ...
    start_time = time.time()
    def callback():
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - start_time > 1.0:
            print 'working'
            start_time = time.time()
    work_function(args, callback)
```

Since `start_time` is local the `global` keyword won't work inside `callback`.  Is there a Python paradigm that can handle adding state to local functions?

Comment: I think you need to better define what you mean by state?  often you can .... but this does not seem to be an optimal solution based on the info you have provided ...

Comment: Do you mean a closure?

Comment: Reference: (not duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/q/233673/758446

Comment: Use nonlocal.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement

Comment: Seems like a class would be a better solution here.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but it's a very well-asked and useful one - it should help search engine results and won't mislead future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already suggested, you're probably better off using a class, and saving the state as a member.

Also as already suggested, you can use a global variable, or the `nonlocal` statement.

A third (and more original) alternative would be to set the state as an attribute of the *function object*:

```
def main_func()
    ...
    def callback():
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - callback.start_time > 1.0:
            print 'working'
            callback.start_time = time.time()
    callback.start_time = time.time()
    work_function(args, callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work, though the details will depend on which version of Python you're using.

In Python 3, you can use a `nonlocal` statement to allow your `callback` function to assign a new value to the `start_time` variable in the outer function's scope.

```
def main_func()
    ...
    start_time = time.time()
    def callback():
        nonlocal start_time            # new line here
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - start_time > 1.0:
            print 'working'
            start_time = time.time()   # this assignment now works as intended
    work_function(args, callback)
```

In Python 2, `nonlocal` is not available, but you can wrap the value up in a mutable container (like a `list`) and modify the value without reassigning the variable:

```
def main_func()
    ...
    start_time = [time.time()]             # wrap time value in a list
    def callback():
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - start_time > 1.0:
            print 'working'
            start_time[0] = time.time()    # modify the list in place
    work_function(args, callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda, but it's durdly.

```
    def foo(a):
        def inner(b):
            if b > c[0]:
                c[0] > b
            else:
                print "too low"
        c = [a]
        return inner

>>> bar = foo(5)
>>> bar(5)
too low
>>> bar(6) # silence on success
>>> bar(5)
too low
```

As others have pointed out, it's probably best to just use an object (which you kind of do with this solution -- lists are objects after all)

Comment: This sort of approach is only required in 2.x, where `nonlocal` isn't available.