# Matrix Constraints with Scipy.Optimize.Minimize

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm trying out python's scipy.optimize to minimize some function using the SLSQP algorithm. The optimization seems to work fine unconstrained and with one matrix constraint, but then I get an error when I add a second matrix constraint.

```
import nlopt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

n = 3
n_sim = 10000
risk_aversion = 5

Y = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(n_sim, n))

mu_Y = np.mean(Y, axis=0).reshape(1, n)
sigma_Y = np.cov(Y, rowvar=0, bias=1)

x0 = np.ones((n, 1)) / n

Aeq = np.ones((1, n))
beq = 1
A =  np.array([[1, 1, 0], [-1, -1, 0]])
b = np.array([[0.25], [-0.5]])

def func(x, mu, sigma, risk_aversion):
    return -np.dot(mu, x) + 0.5 * risk_aversion * np.dot(np.dot(x.T, sigma), x)
def func_deriv(x, sigma, risk_aversion):
    return risk_aversion * np.dot(sigma, x)

c_ = {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : lambda x: np.dot(Aeq, x) - beq, 'jac' : lambda x: Aeq}
b_ = [(0,1) for i in range(n)]
```

This version with one constraint and bounds works fine

```
res = minimize(lambda x: func(x, mu_Y, sigma_Y, risk_aversion), x0, 
               jac=lambda x: func_deriv(x, sigma_Y, risk_aversion), 
               constraints=c_, bounds=b_, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})
```

However, the two constraint version gives me an error

```
d_ = (c_,
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun' : lambda x: np.dot(A, x) - b, 'jac' : lambda x: A})

res2 = minimize(lambda x: func(x, mu_Y, sigma_Y, risk_aversion), x0, 
                jac=lambda x: func_deriv(x, sigma_Y, risk_aversion), 
                constraints=d_, bounds=b_, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use

```
A =  np.array([-1, -1, 0])
b = -0.5
```

instead of what I had originally, then the optimization works. This suggests that I can't do a matrix of constraints (like I would with fmincon in Matlab), unless someone can confirm otherwise. However, I can just keep adding constraints such that it will work. The constraints have to be in the form of tuples of dictionaries, so I put together

```
d = []
for i in range(0, b.size):
    d.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun' : lambda x: np.dot(A[i, ], x) - b[i], 'jac' : lambda x: A[i, ]})
d_ = tuple(d)
c_tuple = c_,
d_ = d_ + c_tuple
```

which seems to be working properly.

Comment: When appending stuff to the constraint dict in a for loop, be careful about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/lexical-closures-in-python

Comment: @pv My goal was more to get it to work well enough so that I could compare the basic performance to nlopt. nlopt was about 3x faster, so I'm going to focus more on using that (which does not require this syntax).