# Usage of local variables in closures when accessing Spark RDDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, closures, rdd

I have a question regarding the usage of local variables in closures when accessing Spark RDDs. The problem I would like to solve looks as follows:

I have a list of textfiles that should be read into an RDD.
However, first I need to add additional information to an RDD that is created from a single textfile. This additional information is extracted from the filename. Then, the RDDs are put into one big RDD using union().

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTest")
spark_context = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)

list_of_filenames = ['file_from_Ernie.txt', 'file_from_Bert.txt']
rdd_list = []
for filename in list_of_filenames:
    tmp_rdd = spark_context.textFile(filename)
    # extract_file_info('file_from_Owner.txt') == 'Owner'
    file_owner = extract_file_info(filename)   
    tmp_rdd = tmp_rdd.map(lambda x : (x, file_owner))
    rdd_list.append(tmp_rdd)
overall_content_rdd = spark_context.union(rdd_list)
# ...do something...
overall_content_rdd.collect()
# However, this does not work: 
# The result is that always Bert will be the owner, i.e., never Ernie.
```

The problem is that the map() function within the loop does not refer to the “correct” file_owner. Instead, it will refer to the latest value of file_owner. On my local machine, I managed to fix the problem by calling the cache() function for each single RDD:

```
# ..
tmp_rdd = tmp_rdd.map(lambda x : (x, file_owner))
tmp_rdd.cache()
# ..
```

**My Question: Is using cache() the correct solution for my problem? Are there any alternatives?**

Many Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating functions (or lambdas) in a loop (or comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-or-lambdas-in-a-loop-or-comprehension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the cache() method that you are doing won't necessarily work 100% of the time, it works provided that no nodes fail and no partitions need to be recomputed. A simple solution would be to make a function that will "capture" the value of file_owner. Here is a quick little illustration in the pyspark shell of a potential solution:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014 22:59:56)
SparkContext available as sc.
>>> hi = "hi"
>>> sc.parallelize(["panda"])
ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:365
>>> r = sc.parallelize(["panda"])
>>> meeps = r.map(lambda x : x + hi)
>>> hi = "by"
>>> meeps.collect()
['pandaby']
>>> hi = "hi"
>>> def makeGreetFunction(param):
...     return (lambda x: x + param)
... 
>>> f = makeGreetFunction(hi)
>>> hi="by"
>>> meeps = r.map(f)
>>> meeps.collect()
['pandahi']
>>>
```

Comment: Great, this works! 
Could you please elaborate a bit more _why_ it actually works with such a separate function or provide a pointer to the Spark documentation. Thx!

Comment: As Daniel Darabos suggested this is more a property of Python rather than a property of Spark. The implications of cache() are Spark specific, the Spark programming guide (under RDDs) covers how Spark may recompute RDDs http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Spark phenomenon, but a plain Python one.

```
>>> fns = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...   fns.append(lambda: i)
... 
>>> for fn in fns:
...   print fn()
... 
2
2
2
```

One way to avoid it is to declare functions which default arguments. The default value is evaluated at the time of declaration.

```
>>> fns = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...   def f(i=i):
...     return i
...   fns.append(f)
... 
>>> for fn in fns:
...   print fn()
... 
0
1
2
```

This comes up a lot, see these other questions:

- [Lexical closures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/lexical-closures-in-python)
- [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python)

Comment: Here is the way to implement working code with lambdas and list comprehensions:
`fns = [(lambda i: lambda: i)(i) for i in range(3)]`

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of file owners and use that in the map transformation:

```
file_owner[i] = extract_file_info(filename)
tmp_rdd = tmp_rdd.map(lambda x : (x, file_owner[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As others explained, the problem with your lambda function is that it will evaluate `file_owner` at the time of execution. To force its evaluation during the iteration of your for loop, you have to create **and execute** construction function. Here is how to do it with lambdas:

```
# ...
file_owner = extract_file_info(filename)   
tmp_rdd = tmp_rdd.map((lambda owner: lambda line: (line,owner))(file_owner))
# ...
```