# Spark Scala throws "java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found" with Broadcast variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a broadcast variable which is constructed in the following manner

```
// Function
def loadMovieNames(sparkContext: SparkContext): Map[Int, String] = {

    // Handle character encoding issues:
    implicit val codec = Codec("UTF-8")
    codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    codec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)

    // Create a Map of Ints to Strings, and populate it from u.item.
    var movieNames: Map[Int, String] = Map()

    val lines = sparkContext.textFile("s3a://bucket/movies.dat")
    for (line <- lines) {
        var fields = line.split("::")
        if (fields.length > 1) {
        movieNames += (fields(0).toInt -> fields(1))
        }
    }

    return movieNames
}

// Main
val nameDict = loadMovieNames(spark.sparkContext)
val broadcastNames = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(nameDict)
```

Below is the code in main used to access the broadcast variable.

```
val resultDF = recommendationsDF.sort($"score".desc).limit(30)

val check = (id1: Int, id2: Int) => if (id1 == movie) broadcastNames.value(id2) else broadcastNames.value(id1)

val getName = udf(check)

val results = resultDF.withColumn("movie", getName($"movieId1", $"movieId2"))

results.show(30)
```

But when I try to do a lookup in the broadcast variable later in main, I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 1196
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
at com.spark.movierec.MovieRecDF$$anonfun$5.apply(MovieRecDF.scala:144)
at com.spark.movierec.MovieRecDF$$anonfun$5.apply(MovieRecDF.scala:143)
```

I converted the Map to a broadcast variable when I initially ran into the same issue. After reading the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311296/spark-throws-java-util-nosuchelementexception-key-not-found-67), I've realized it could be an issue with closures. But I'm still not sure how to tackle the issue.

Comment: You might want to consider using the get method of Map rather than the apply method. The former yields an Option[V], in your case, Option[String] which you can then deal with in a logical manner. The problem with apply is that it will throw an exception if you don't provide a default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to create a local map is to use `collectAsMap`:

```
val nameDict = sparkContext.broadcast(sparkContext
  .textFile(path)
  .map(_.split("::"))
  .filter(_.size > 1)
  .map(arr => (arr(0).toInt, arr(1)))
  .collectAsMap())
```

You should also consider using `DataFrames` and broadcast join in place of UDF and broadcast variable, but the logic of you application is not that clear.