# Iterative function generation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Consider the following idea: I want to generate a sequence of functions `f_k`, 
for `k = 1,...,50` and store them in a Python dictionary. 
To give a concrete example, lets say

```
f_k(x)  = f_{k-1}(x) * sqrt(x)
```

This is just an example, the problem I have is more complicated, but this does not matter for my question. 
Because in my real problem `f_{k-1}` is very noisy and contains rounding errors, I do not want to build `f_k` directly from `f_{k-1}`, but instead
I first approximate `f_{k-1}` through a spline approximation, and then determine `f_k` from that spline approximation. Strangely, this results in an error message saying that maximum recursion depth is exceeded. Here is an example of the code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
n = 50 # number of functions I want to create
args = np.linspace(1,4,20) # where to evaluate for spline approximation
fdict = dict() # dictionary that stores all the functions
fdict[0] = lambda x: x**2 # the first function

# generate function f_k as follows: First, take function f_{k-1} and 
# approximate it through a spline. Multiply that spline approximation 
# by sqrt(x) and store this as function f_k. 
for k in range(1,n+1):

    spline_approx = lambda x: interp1d( args,fdict[k-1](args) )(x)
    fdict[k] = lambda x: spline_approx(x) * np.sqrt(x)

 print('test evalutation: ', fdict[n](3))
```

This results in the error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

My problem must be very Python specific. It must have something to do with the interpolation through interp1d. 
For instance. If I replace the line

```
spline_approx = lambda x: interp1d( args,fdict[k-1](args) )(x)
```

by a polyfit

```
coefs = np.polyfit(args,fdict[k-1](args),10) # polyfit coefficients
spline_approx = lambda x: np.polyval(coefs,x) # approximation of f_{k-1}
```

the code runs fine. I suspect that the problem arises because `fdict[k-1]` is not directly evaluated but only passed on as a reference. But how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line that raises the `RecursionError` is indeed:

```
spline_approx = lambda x: interp1d( args,fdict[k-1](args) )(x)
```

This line means that `spline_approx` is the function that, given `x`, returns `interp1d(args, fdict[k-1](args)` evaluated in `x`.

Since `interp1d` returns the function that you want to put into `spline_approx`, this line can be simplified into:

```
spline_approx = interp1d( args,fdict[k-1](args) )
```

which will stop throwing `RecursionError`.

---

Why does your original code throw a `RecursionError`?

In the original line, `interp1d(args, fdict[k-1](args))` is **not** evaluated, because it is inside of a `lambda` expression. This evaluation is postponed to the call of that `lambda` expression.

In other words, every time you call a function from `fdict`, all the previous functions must evaluate `interp1d(args, fdict[k-1](args))`. The problem is that `args` is a sequence, so `fdict[k-1]` is called as many times as `args` has elements.

The number of calls is of course exponential, since every function must evaluate the precedent function `len(args)` times. Which results in a `RecursionError`.

On the other hand, the new expression does evaluate `interp1d(args, fdict[k-1](args))`. After this evaluation, a call to `fdict[k]` will not trigger a call to `fdict[k-1]` anymore.

Comment: Good answer. It is worth mentioning [lexical closures.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/lexical-closures-in-python)