# Binding of lambdas

Tags: python

```
def f(x):
    return x <5
[x for x in filter(lambda x: f(x), ls)]  #[0,1,2,3,4]
def g(x):
    return lambda: x<5
[x for x in filter(lambda x: g(x), ls)]  # [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def h(x):
    return lambda x=x: x<5
[x for x in filter(lambda x: h(x), ls)]  # [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Can anyone explain why g and h are not equivalent to f? 
I think they should be equivalent because x in g and h should bind to the x in the environment that they are defined in (see this [question on closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/lexical-closures-in-python))

Comment: `f` returns a boolean. `g` and `h` return functions. Why would they be equivalent?

Comment: a function in a conditional statement always considered as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `g` and `h` return function object, but `filter` waits an function which returns a boolean or [object wich will convert as boolean](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) . With `f` it is correct for your expected output, but for `g` and `h`, the condition is always `true` because `bool(function object)` is always `true` see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable), a python function is a callable object.

Take:

```
def f(x):
    return x < 5

def g(x):
    return lambda: x < 5

def h(x):
    return lambda x=x: x < 5
```

I advise to do:

```
ls = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print([x for x in ls if f(x)]) # list comprehension
# is equivalent to filter(lambda x: x < 5, ls) iterator
# To get list :
# [x for x in filter(lambda x: x < 5, ls)]
# is equivalent to list(filter(lambda x: x < 5, ls))
```

Output:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

To call `g` to do:

```
g(1)() # True
```

Do:

```
 print([x for x in ls if g(x)()])
```

Output:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

To call `h` to do:

```
h(1)() # True
```

or

```
h(1)(5) # False the second argument overrides the first one
```

Do:

```
print([x for x in ls if h(x)(x)])
# or print([x for x in ls if h(x)()])
```

Output:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to use **filter**:

> Construct a list from those elements of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If iterable is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type; otherwise it is always a list. If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.
>
> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]` if function is not `None` and `[item for item in iterable if item]` if function is `None`.

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to use **lambda expression**:

`lambda arguments: expression` with :

```
def <lambda>(arguments):
    return expression
```

Answer (score 0):

`g(x)` and `h(x)` are returning the `lambda` function itself (`<function __main__.<lambda>>`), but not executing it.

Try for example: `g(3)()` that will return the desired value.

Therefore running `g(x)()` or `h(x)()` will work:

```
[x for x in filter(lambda x: g(x)(), ls)]  # [0,1,2,3,4]
[x for x in filter(lambda x: h(x)(), ls)]  # [0,1,2,3,4]
```

While running only `g(x)` or `h(x)` will return the `lambda` function itself per each value, which is equivalent to `True` statement in `filter` function, and therefore no value is filtered.

---

and of course, in this case you can just run:

```
filter(lambda x: x<5, ls)
```

or even a [better list comprehension approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter):

```
[x for x in ls if x<5]
```