# Method to create lambda functions from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, lambda

### Preface

Though this problem references the `pandas` and `numpy` packages I believe a solution does not require working knowledge of either of these packages.

### Setup

I wish to create a dictionary of lambda functions to pass to the formatter argument of the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) function [pandas.DataFrame.to_latex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html).

I would like the dictionary of lambda functions to format floats to a number of digits as specified by a list.

### Example

What I would like to achieve may best be seen by example. Let's set up some floats we'd like to format:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = np.array([[0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345]])
colnames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=colnames)

#print(df)
#      col1     col2     col3
#0  0.12345  0.12345  0.12345
```

Excellent, now I'd like to format column `col1` to show 1 digit after the decimal point. Similarly, I'd like to format `col2` to show 2 digits after the decimal point and `col3` to display 3 digits. Let's set up a list with this intention:

```py
digits = [1, 2, 3]
```

From this list we shall create a dict of lambda functions to format the columns, and test the functions after creation.

```py
fun = {}

for id, col in enumerate(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']):
    fun[col] = lambda x : '{{:.{}f}}'.format(digits[id]).format(x)
    print(fun[col](0.12345))
    # Prints 0.1, 0.12, 0.123 (looks to have worked!)
```

In the code above printing on creation of each entry appears I have achieved what I wished to. However, looking again I see I was mistaken

```py
print(fun['col1'](0.12345)) # Prints 0.123
print(fun['col2'](0.12345)) # Prints 0.123
print(fun['col3'](0.12345)) # Prints 0.123
```

I understand that these functions all format the float the same as `digits[id] = 3` after the loop.

I would like to alter how I create the lambda functions such that we instead observe:

```py
print(fun['col1'](0.12345)) # Prints 0.1
print(fun['col2'](0.12345)) # Prints 0.12
print(fun['col3'](0.12345)) # Prints 0.123
```

Is it possible to do this? I imagine a solution may involve use of `eval` but I can't figure it out.

### Obvious solution

Outside of the context of `pd.DataFrame.to_latex`, we could create a single lambda function which takes two arguments and formats floats as desired:

```py
fun = lambda x, digit : '{{:.{}f}}'.format(digit).format(x)

print(fun(0.12345, digits[0])) # Prints 0.1
print(fun(0.12345, digits[1])) # Prints 0.12
print(fun(0.12345, digits[2])) # Prints 0.123
```

However, as far as I understand the formatter functions passed to `pd.DataFrame.to_latex` may only take a single argument and so such a solution would not be viable.

Comment: I guess that the title of your question is misleading. Probably you would like to know more about closures, so you will find several answers to your question for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/how-do-lexical-closures-work)

Comment: @JoergVanAken You're right, I didn't know about closures and struggled to articulate because of this. Your link helped me understand and was very informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the value of float resolution at the time of looping, otherwise the 3 lambda closures refers to the same `id` variable and all of them get the last value assigned to `id`.

A possible solution using [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
def col_resolution(resolution, x):
    return '{{:.{}f}}'.format(resolution).format(x)

for id, col in enumerate(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']):
    fun[col] = partial(col_resolution, digits[id])

    # one line with lambda
    # fun[col] = partial(lambda res, x : '{{:.{}f}}'.format(res).format(x), digits[id])
```

Comment: Excellent. This works as desired. I also found

```fun[col] = lambda x, digits=digits[id] : '{{:.{}f}}'.format(digits).format(x)``` binds ```digits[id]``` during the loop.